# Disable browsers vertical and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to disable the browsers vertical and horizontal scrollbars using jQuery or javascript?

Comment: I think in some situations specially if you want to toggle between scroll and no scroll this solution is more preferable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it

Comment: You can find a more complete answer to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25561646/1922144

Answer (score 147):

In case you need possibility to hide and show scrollbars dynamically you could use

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

and

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```

somewhere in your code.

Comment: Overflow hidden does not always work in IE. See AnthonyWJones answer below.

Comment: `oveflow: hidden` won't prevent anything on smartphones.

Comment: In chrome, this disables the scrollbar without hiding it (it is still there and still changing the size of everything else, but now its grayed out)

Answer (score 133):

```
function reloadScrollBars() {
    document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto';  // firefox, chrome
    document.body.scroll = "yes"; // ie only
}

function unloadScrollBars() {
    document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
    document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only
}
```

Comment: Two upvotes is remarkably little for being the only pure javascript answer.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson: Seeing OP asked for JavaScript or jQuery solution and had accepted a jQuery solution 4 years ago it only makes sense. I'm not saying the answer is not good, just stating the obvious about the lower votes. +1 from me anyway.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me, since the body hidden overflow doesn't attack the whole document, this is the right solution for this problem! thanks so much, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: This is a brilliant solution and deserves an upvote. It also solves issue with fixed css, where page will be scroll to top.

Answer (score 50):

Try CSS

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
```

Comment: For browser compatibility I'd add this style to the HTML tag as well:

html, body {overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 31):

So far we have overflow:hidden on the body.  However IE doesn't always honor that and you need to put scroll="no" on the body element as well and/or place overflow:hidden on the html element as well.

You can take this further when you need to 'take control' of the view port you can do this:-

```
<style>
 body {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:0; }
 html {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
</style>
```

An element granted height 100% in the body has the full height of the window viewport, and element positioned absolutely using bottom:nnPX will be set nn pixels above the bottom edge of the window, etc.

Comment: dosen't the ',' should be ';',in the body css?

Answer (score 12):

Try CSS.

If you want to remove Horizontal

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

And if you want to remove Vertical

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Answer (score 10):

In modern versions of IE (IE10 and above), scrollbars can be hidden using the [`-ms-overflow-style` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
html {
     -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

In Chrome, scrollbars can be styled:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

This is very useful if you want to use the 'default' body scrolling in a web application, which is considerably faster than `overflow-y: scroll`.

Comment: only this has worked for me from all the answers :) thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In case you also need support for Internet Explorer 6, just overflow the **html**

```
$("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

and

```
$("html").css("overflow", "auto");
```

Answer (score 5):

IE has some bug with the scrollbars. So if you want either of the two, you must include the following to hide the horizontal scrollbar:

`overflow-x: hidden;`
`overflow-y:scroll;`

and to hide vertical:

`overflow-y: hidden;`
`overflow-x: scroll;`

Answer (score 4):

(I can't comment yet, but wanted to share this):

Lyncee's code worked for me in desktop browser. However, on iPad (Chrome, iOS 9), it crashed the application. To fix it, I changed

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = ...
```

to

```
document.body.style.overflow = ...
```

which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because Firefox has an arrow key short cut, you probably want to put a `<div>` around it with CSS style: `overflow:hidden;`.

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery you can disable scrolling bar with this code :

```
$('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
     }
});
```

Also you can enable it again with this code :

```
 $('body').unbind('mousewheel');
```