# Hiding the scroll bar on an HTML page

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar

Can CSS be used to hide the scroll bar? How would you do this?

Comment: @UweKeim, there's no trick for IE11

Answer (score 432, accepted):

Set **[`overflow: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values)** on the `body` tag like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

The code above "hides" both the horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

If you want to hide **only the vertical scrollbar**, use [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

And if you want to hide **only the horizontal scrollbar**, use [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

---

> Content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding box. No scrollbars are provided, and no support for allowing the user to scroll (such as by dragging or using a scroll wheel) is allowed. The content can be scrolled programmatically (for example, by setting the value of a property such as [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)), so *the element **is** still a scroll container*. <sub>([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values))</sub>

Comment: There is no "none" option for overflow property. Available options include: visible, hidden, scroll, auto, inherit.

Comment: Actually, this is not completely the right answer : overflow:hidden doesn't "hide" the scrollbar. It also stop scrolling feature on the page. That's not exactly what we ask for.

Comment: In Chrome, when body overflow is set to `hidden` scrolling will work with a mouse scroller wheel. In Firefox, scrolling will not work with a mouse scroller wheel, it took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: Just a heads up, designers for firefox, chrome, and others say that The scrollbar is a touchy subject, it "crosses" the page's boundary into the window manager's domain. Technically speaking, web pages aren't supposed to be able to modify the user's windowing widgets, just like you cant tell a web page to use different graphics for buttons of a titlebar for a window or have a different dialog colors, etc... some extensions do let you do this, but its a pretty big debate, look on **MDN** for now 'depreciated' section of -moz extensions that were considered intrusive on users' operating systems.

Comment: Not working in Chrome v31.  I don't think this is the intended use case for overflow:hidden.

Comment: Technically a correct answer, but the desired behavior is only accomplished as a side effect of enabling a behavior not necessarily desired.

Comment: I don't see the point in asserting that `overflow: hidden` disables scrolling. If someone wants to hide the scrollbar, then presumably they deem the control unnecessary because *there is no content to scroll in the first place*. Or perhaps *they just don't want to allow scrolling altogether*.

Comment: Besides, the assertions aren't entirely correct. You can still scroll the element through unconventional means such as tabbing through any focusable descendants, or by using JavaScript to force a scroll. If you still want the user to have the ability to scroll the element somehow, you can always wire up a new scrolling mechanism using JavaScript. Or, you know, you could just not hide the default scrollbar - which the browser draws for you, automatically and completely for free! - to begin with.

Comment: To me the assertion is perfectly valid, as the question is to *hide the scrollbar*, not to *disable scrolling*.

Comment: @BoltClock An example use case of this being valid is for responsive sites, on mobiles the it is clear to use your finger, where as on a desktop it wouldn't be required but would still show.

Comment: @tim.baker: Most mobile platforms draw scrollbars only on scroll, so I don't see a problem there. On desktop you can set overflow: auto if you want the scrollbar to show only when necessary. Unless I misunderstand you...

Comment: @sboisse: You can't hide the only visual cue to a desktop user that scrolling is possible and still expect them to be able to scroll (this isn't a problem on mobile, as I've just now stated in reply to a recent comment). Even if you don't believe my claim that overflow: hidden does not in fact disable scrolling, Googling `javascript scrollbar` turns up dozens of solutions including [this example](http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/examples/nojquery) where you can clearly see that the .viewport element has overflow: hidden, and yet it can be scrolled (with a UX far worse than the default, no less).

Comment: @BoltClock: Overflow: hidden does disable scrolling, else the mousewheel would work in both boxes in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjko9ryz/ and onscroll events would trigger as well. Of course workarounds exist with Javascript, but are never as robust, and sometimes, the same behaviour just can't be met as with the native scrollbar.

Comment: @sboisse: I think we have to be clear what disabling scrolling actually entails in this context - let's agree that it means "disabling scrolling UI". That is, overflow: hidden prevents the *user* from scrolling an element, and it does that by 1) preventing the mousewheel from scrolling the element 2) hiding the scrollbars, the only visual cue to the user that they can scroll. It's hard to glean from the original question, but if the requirement *is* to hide the scrollbar while still allowing the user to scroll, then I can only point readers back to my very first comment here.

Comment: @BoltClock: There are so many situations why a developer might want to have a scrollable element without the native scrollbar. For example, implementing another visual cue to replace the native scrollbar because the native scrollbar cannot be styled in a harmonious way with a website theme is probably the most obvious use case where this would be useful, and probably why so many people came here on that page, looking for a way to do this. By saying this, you are saying the native scrollbar should be the only acceptable visual cue for a scrollable element. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: ANP wants to hide scroll-bar not text. This disables scrolling.

Comment: @BoltClock

this is ages old, but im gonna throw an example out there.
I have a card of fixed height, with content that overflows.
Scrollbar looks terrible with my design.
I want to hide the scrollbar and create my own visual cue without having to develop or use a third party js function that people would need to have downloaded, and could be blocked by disabling javascript.

Its much easier to use a little CSS to hide the scroll bar, use the default scroll behavior, and add a small down arrow at the bottom of the pane holding overflow content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23771140/1616697 this should be the correct answer by thgaskell

Comment: Check Peter answer for this question (Below.  It is the most up voted one).  That one should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The reason that I want to hide the scrollbar is because the browsers make such ugly scrollbars these days.

Comment: This does not work to hide scroll bars for certain dynamic elements like resizeable textarea.

Comment: You need to also set height: 100vh as well as overflow: hidden, this hides the scrollbar but desn't stop scrolling

Answer (score 1108):

WebKit supports scrollbar pseudo elements that can be hidden with standard CSS rules:

```css
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want all scrollbars hidden, use

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm not sure about restoring - this did work, but there might be a right way to do it:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block;
}
```

You can of course always use `width: 0`, which can then be easily restored with `width: auto`, but I'm not a fan of abusing `width` for visibility tweaks.

Firefox 64 now supports the experimental [scrollbar-width property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) by default (63 requires a configuration flag to be set). To hide the scrollbar in Firefox 64:

```css
#element {
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

To see if your current browser supports either the pseudo element or `scrollbar-width`, try this snippet:

```css
.content {
  /* These rules create an artificially confined space, so we get
     a scrollbar that we can hide. They are not directly involved in
     hiding the scrollbar. */

  border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: .5em;

  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 5em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  /* This is the magic bit for Firefox */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* This is the magic bit for WebKit */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu
urna et leo aliquet malesuada ut ac dolor. Fusce non arcu vel ligula
fermentum sodales a quis sapien. Sed imperdiet justo sit amet venenatis
egestas. Integer vitae tempor enim. In dapibus nisl sit amet purus congue
tincidunt. Morbi tincidunt ut eros in rutrum. Sed quam erat, faucibus
vel tempor et, elementum at tortor. Praesent ac libero at arcu eleifend
mollis ut eget sapien. Duis placerat suscipit eros, eu tempor tellus
facilisis a. Vivamus vulputate enim felis, a euismod diam elementum
non. Duis efficitur ac elit non placerat. Integer porta viverra nunc,
sed semper ipsum. Nam laoreet libero lacus.

Sed sit amet tincidunt felis. Sed imperdiet, nunc ut porta elementum,
eros mi egestas nibh, facilisis rutrum sapien dolor quis justo. Quisque
nec magna erat. Phasellus vehicula porttitor nulla et dictum. Sed
tincidunt scelerisque finibus. Maecenas consequat massa aliquam pretium
volutpat. Duis elementum magna vel velit elementum, ut scelerisque
odio faucibus.
</div>
```

---

*(Note that this is not really a correct answer to the question, because it hides the horizontal bars as well, but that's what I was looking for when Google pointed me here, so I figured I'd post it anyway.)*

Comment: Just what I was looking for since I really wanted to hide the scrollbars but have the elements still scrollable (e.g. up/down keys)

Comment: this should be the best answer since other solutions don't let you scroll

Comment: Does this support other browsers apart from webkit? Because it does not work in mozilla.

Comment: It's webkit only. Hence the vendor prefix.

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) on the Mozilla tracker though. You may be able to speed up the implementation by voting for it over there :)

Comment: The Mozilla feature request has really little votes! Wish more people voted for this :/

Comment: its not working on mozilla.but i liked it ty for answer.

Comment: I believe that this is the correct way to reset this.

::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: initial; 
}

Comment: Tried it in IE11 and it does not work, all the scrollbars are shown. I tried it in Opera and Google Chrome, it worked perfectly fine. This is great answer though. Thanks!

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER! As others are missing. The problem is not just hiding the scrollbar, but how the overflow affects other styles. I ran into this exact same problem in our app. We do NOT want overflow auto on 99% of the app, however there is a help section where you want the user to be able to scroll down. Since the body has overflow:hidden, the only wan to handle this was an ng-class on the root, or thanks to this guys, just using some CSS.

Comment: I tried all kinds of stuff for a very long time now, ended up using [perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar)

Comment: Try out `display: unset` instead of `display: block`

Answer (score 559):

### Yes, sort of..

When you ask the question, "Can the scroll-bars of a browser be removed in some way, rather than simply hidden or camouflaged", everyone will say "Not possible" because it is not possible to *remove* the scrollbars from all browsers in a compliant and cross-compatible way, and then there's the whole argument of usability.

However, it is possible to prevent the browser from ever having the need to generate and display scrollbars if you do not allow your webpage to overflow.

This just means that we have to proactively substitute the same behavior that the browser would typically do for us and tell the browser thanks but no thanks buddy.  Rather than try to remove scrollbars (which we all know is not possible) we can avoid scrolling (perfectly feasible) and scroll within the elements that we make and have more control over.

Create a div with overflow hidden. Detect when the user attempts to scroll, but is unable to because we've disabled the browsers ability to scroll with overflow: hidden.. and instead move the content up using JavaScript when this occurs. Thereby creating our own scrolling without the browsers default scrolling or use a plugin like [iScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll).

### ---

*For the sake of being thorough; all the vendor specific ways of manipulating scroll-bars:*

### Internet Explorer 5.5+

*These properties were never part of the CSS specification, nor were they ever approved or vendor prefixed, but they work in Internet Explorer and Konqueror. These can also be set locally in the user style sheet for each application. In Internet Explorer you find it under the "Accessibility" tab, in Konqueror under the "Stylesheets" tab.

```
body, html { /* These are defaults and can be replaced by hexadecimal color values */
    scrollbar-base-color: aqua;
    scrollbar-face-color: ThreeDFace;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: ThreeDHighlight;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: ThreeDLightShadow;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow;
    scrollbar-track-color: Scrollbar;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: ButtonText;
}
```

As of Internet Explorer 8 these properties were vendor prefixed by Microsoft, but they were still never approved by [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium).

```
-ms-scrollbar-base-color
-ms-scrollbar-face-color
-ms-scrollbar-highlight-color
-ms-scrollbar-3dlight-color
-ms-scrollbar-shadow-color
-ms-scrollbar-darkshadow-color
-ms-scrollbar-base-color
-ms-scrollbar-track-color
```

#### Further details about Internet Explorer

Internet Explorer makes `scroll` available which sets whether or not to disable or enable scroll bars; it can also be used to get the value of the position of the scroll bars.

With Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 and later, when you use the `!DOCTYPE` declaration to specify standards-compliant mode, this attribute applies to the HTML element. When standards-compliant mode is not specified, as with earlier versions of Internet Explorer, this attribute applies to the `BODY` element, **NOT** the `HTML` element.

It's also worth noting that when working with .NET the ScrollBar class in `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives` in the Presentation framework is responsible for rendering the scrollbars.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534393(v=vs.85).aspx

- [MSDN. Basic UI properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [W3C. About non-standard scrollbar properties](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/scrollbars.en.html)
- [MSDN. .NET ScrollBar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.scrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

### WebKit

WebKit extensions related to scroll-bar customization are:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {}             /* 1 */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {}      /* 2 */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {}       /* 3 */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {} /* 4 */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {}       /* 5 */
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {}      /* 6 */
::-webkit-resizer {}               /* 7 */
```

[image]

These can each be combined with additional pseudo-selectors:

- `:horizontal` – The horizontal pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces that have a horizontal orientation.
- `:vertical` – The vertical pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces that have a vertical orientation.
- `:decrement` – The decrement pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether or not the button or track piece will decrement the view’s position when used (e.g., up on a vertical scrollbar, left on a horizontal scrollbar).
- `:increment` – The increment pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether or not a button or track piece will increment the view’s position when used (e.g., down on a vertical scrollbar, right on a horizontal scrollbar).
- `:start` – The start pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether the object is placed before the thumb.
- `:end` – The end pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether the object is placed after the thumb.
- `:double-button` – The double-button pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It is used to detect whether a button is part of a pair of buttons that are together at the same end of a scrollbar. For track pieces it indicates whether the track piece abuts a pair of buttons.
- `:single-button` – The single-button pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It is used to detect whether a button is by itself at the end of a scrollbar. For track pieces it indicates whether the track piece abuts a singleton button.
- `:no-button` – Applies to track pieces and indicates whether or not the track piece runs to the edge of the scrollbar, i.e., there is no button at that end of the track.
- `:corner-present` – Applies to all scrollbar pieces and indicates whether or not a scrollbar corner is present.
- `:window-inactive` – Applies to all scrollbar pieces and indicates whether or not the window containing the scrollbar is currently active. (In recent nightlies, this pseudo-class now applies to ::selection as well. We plan to extend it to work with any content and to propose it as a new standard pseudo-class.)

**Examples of these combinations**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start { /* Select the top half (or left half) or scrollbar track individually */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { /* Select the thumb when the browser window isn't in focus */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement:hover { /* Select the down or left scroll button when it's being hovered by the mouse */ }
```

- [Styling Scrollbars - Webkit.org](https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/)

#### Further details about Chrome

> **addWindowScrollHandler**
>   public static HandlerRegistration addWindowScrollHandler(Window.ScrollHandler handler)
>
> Adds a Window.ScrollEvent handler
>   Parameters:
>     handler - the handler
>   Returns:
>     returns the handler registration
>   [*source*](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addWindowScrollHandler(com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.ScrollHandler)
>   )

---

### Mozilla

Mozilla does have some extensions for manipulating the scroll-bars, but they are all recommended not to be used.

- `-moz-scrollbars-none` They recommend using overflow:hidden in place of this.
- `-moz-scrollbars-horizontal` Similar to overflow-x
- `-moz-scrollbars-vertical` Similar to overflow-y
- `-moz-hidden-unscrollable` Only works internally within a users profile settings. Disables scrolling XML root elements and disables using arrow keys and mouse wheel to scroll web pages.
- [Mozilla Developer Docs on 'Overflow'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

#### Further details about Mozilla

This is not really useful as far as I know, but it's worth noting that the attribute which controls whether or not scrollbars are displayed in Firefox is ([reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindow)):

- **Attribute:**       scrollbars
- **Type:**              nsIDOMBarProp
- **Description:**  The object that controls whether or not scrollbars are shown in the window. This attribute is "replaceable" in JavaScript. Read only

### Last but not least, padding is like magic.

As has been previously mentioned in some other answers, here is an illustration which is sufficiently self-explanatory.

[image]

---

### History lesson

[image: Scroll bars]

Just because I'm curious, I wanted to learn about the origin of scrollbars, and these are the best references I found.

- [10 Inventions on Scrolling and Scrollbars](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6752.pdf)
- https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hellstrom-textpreview-02.txt
- https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-mrose-blocks-service-01.txt

### Miscellaneous

[In an HTML5 specification draft, the `seamless` attribute was defined to prevent scroll-bars from appearing in iFrames so that they could be blended with surrounding content on a page](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-seamless). Though this element does not appear in the latest revision.

The `scrollbar` BarProp object is a child of the `window` object and represents the user interface element that contains a scrolling mechanism, or some similar interface concept. `window.scrollbars.visible` will return `true` if the scroll bars are visible.

```
interface Window {
  // The current browsing context
  readonly attribute WindowProxy window;
  readonly attribute WindowProxy self;
           attribute DOMString name;
  [PutForwards=href] readonly attribute Location location;
  readonly attribute History history;
  readonly attribute UndoManager undoManager;
  Selection getSelection();
  [Replaceable] readonly attribute BarProp locationbar;
  [Replaceable] readonly attribute BarProp menubar;
  [Replaceable] readonly attribute BarProp personalbar;
  [Replaceable] readonly attribute BarProp scrollbars;
  [Replaceable] readonly attribute BarProp statusbar;
  [Replaceable] readonly attribute BarProp toolbar;
  void close();
  void focus();
  void blur();
  // Truncated
```

The History API also includes features for scroll restoration on page navigation to persist the scroll position on page load.

`window.history.scrollRestoration` can be used to check the status of scrollrestoration or change its status (appending `="auto"/"manual"`. Auto is the default value. Changing it to manual means that you as the developer will take ownership of any scroll changes that may be required when a user traverses the app's history. If you need to, you can keep track of the scroll position as you push history entries with history.pushState().

### ---

## Further reading:

- [Scrollbar on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrollbar)
- [Scroll bar (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787529(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [The Scroll Method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtxlmfr.php)
- [The Scroll Method - Microsoft Dev Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536726(VS.85).aspx)
- [iScroll on Github (referenced in the first section above)](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)
- [Scrolling and Scrollbars an article about usability by Jakob Nielsen](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-scrollbars/)

### Examples

- [Independent scrolling panels with no body scroll (using just CSS) - Ben Frain (10-21-2014)](https://benfrain.com/independent-scrolling-panels-body-scroll-using-just-css/)

Comment: This answer would apply to significantly more browsers (namely IE) rather than the currently upvoted answer.

Comment: Great addition. Actually implemented that same solution today! May be worth mentioning that the other element should be overflow: hidden;

Comment: This is the correct, full featured answer. I explains that if you simply want to stop a user from scrolling you can use the overflow rule. You can also implement your own home built scrolling feature. If that is not enough you can set scroll bar properties directly using different rules for different browsers.

Comment: while this is an incredibly well-thought out answer, and very detailed, and many resources linked, there are massive problems for assistive technology users when you disable scroll and use javascript to handle all the scrolling. If you do not also set focus to an element every time you scroll for the user, then your AT user will be completely lost. Also, your user has now lost all fine-tuned control over what (s)he sees. Very poor UX to take over scrolling for your user.

Comment: Firefox Quantum 63.0.1 on MacOS High Sierra, doesn't hide the scrollbar even with the 'overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none' rule. Anyone knows solution for this? All the other browser seem to work with the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 120):

Here's my solution, which theoretically covers all modern browsers:

```
html {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* For Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; /* For Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}
```

`html` can be replaced with any element you want to hide the scrollbar of.

<sub>**Note**: I've skimmed the other 19 answers to see if the code I'm posting has already been covered, and it seems like no single answer sums up the situation as it stands in 2019, although plenty of them go into excellent detail. Apologies if this has been said by someone else and I missed it.</sub>

Comment: this solution is from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

Comment: According to archive.org, this answer pre-dates that page. And when that page was launched, it didn't have this solution. So I think W3 Schools's solution is from Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: I wish there was a way to allow this for vertical scrolling and not horizontal (or vice versa).

Comment: @lharby There is, just use overflow-x and/or overflow-y.

Comment: @DJFriar that is a different property. One would need `html::-webkit-scrollbar-x html::-webkit-scrollbar-y` etc. but I presume no such thing exists. overflow is a css property, scrollbars are implemented by the browser.

Answer (score 114):

You can accomplish this with a wrapper `div` that has its overflow hidden, and the inner `div` set to `auto`.

To remove the inner `div`'s scroll bar, you can pull it out of the outer `div`'s viewport by applying a negative margin to the inner `div`. Then apply equal padding to the inner div so that the content stays in view.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H47fp/)

###HTML

```
<div class="hide-scroll">
    <div class="viewport">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

###CSS

```
.hide-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.viewport {
    overflow: auto;

    /* Make sure the inner div is not larger than the container
     * so that we have room to scroll.
     */
    max-height: 100%;

    /* Pick an arbitrary margin/padding that should be bigger
     * than the max scrollbar width across the devices that 
     * you are supporting.
     * padding = -margin
     */
    margin-right: -100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo.  Only thing i had to add was `height: inherited` in the `.viewport` css.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is the "dead" space left by the moved scrollbar, because we don't know actually the scrollbar width, in order to subtracts it from the padding.

Comment: Plus, you don't need to use fixed values for the padding and margins. `100%` is more versatile and does the job.

Comment: Worked in IE11, Operah and Chrome, haven't tested Firefox yet. This is great answer, +1.

Comment: why `-100px` and `100px`??

Comment: @BugWhisperer the child `.viewport` element is pushing its sidebar _outside_ of the `.hide-scroll` (which is then hidden). Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4uom12h/

Comment: i know why it works. im just wondering why those specific values? do you also use box-sizing or?

Comment: As the comment in the code mentions. the choice of `100px` is arbitrary. It just needs to be larger than the width of the scrollbar across all browser scrollbars you're supporting. 

This answer doesn't use `box-sizing`. However, if your `.viewport` component has the width set and `box-sizing: border-box` is set, this answer wouldn't work. 

You may have to do something like: `width: calc(100% + 100px)` in order for it to extend outside of the `.hide-scroll` container.

Answer (score 72):

This works for me with simple CSS properties:

```
.container {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  // Internet Explorer 10+
    scrollbar-width: none;  // Firefox
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  // Safari and Chrome
}
```

For older versions of Firefox, use: `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in FireFox 48.0.2 on macOS Sierra. If you do `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;` then you successfully remove the scrollbar, but you also remove the ability to scroll. You might as well just set `overflow: hidden` to the `.container`.

Comment: Oh, and from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow, we read this about `-moz-scrollbars-none`: "This is an obsolete API and is no longer guaranteed to work."

Answer (score 21):

I think I found a workaround for you guys if you're still interested. This is my first week, but it worked for me...

```
<div class="contentScroller">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

.contentScroller {overflow-y: auto; visibility: hidden;}
.content {visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: Works for me in chrome and firefox, haven't tested IE or any other browser.  http://jsfiddle.net/8xtfk729/

Comment: On chrome (v54 at least), this disables scrolling via scroll wheel for some reason. Scroll via arrow keys, home/end/pg down/pg up, touch flick, and mouse 3 click n drag still works.

Comment: This answer is legit, it actually works and appears to work across browsers.

Comment: That hides the whole div on my side

Answer (score 17):

If you're looking for a solution to hide a scrollbar for mobile devices, follow [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page#answer-13184693)!

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45wRp/5/), which uses the solution below to hide a horizontal scrollbar.

```
.scroll-wrapper{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

It was tested on a Samsung tablet with Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich, both in the native browser and Chrome) and on an iPad with iOS 6 (both in Safari and Chrome).

Comment: his answer doesnt work on Chrome and Safari in iOS 12.3

Answer (score 13):

As the other people already said, use CSS `overflow`.

But if you still want the user to be able to scroll that content (without the scrollbar being visible) you have to use JavaScript.

Se my answer here for a solution: *[Hide scrollbar while still being able to scroll with mouse/keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293650/hide-scrollbar-while-still-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-keyboard/)*

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be first. Everything above this does not answer the question at hand. OP does not ask for scrolling disabled, zhe wants to hide the scrollbar.

Answer (score 11):

Use <s>[the CSS `overflow` property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)</s>:

```
.noscroll {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto; /* Or hidden, or visible */
}
```

Here are some more examples:

- *[overflow-x, overflow-y tests](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html)*
- *[The CSS Overflow Property](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)*

Comment: this doesnt actually work in Chrome and Safari on iOS

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Peter's answer:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

This will work the same for Internet Explorer 10:

```
 #element {
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

**Cross browser approach to hiding the scrollbar.**

It was tested on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Hide scrollbar while still being able to scroll with mouse wheel!

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/plumbblake/pen/gLPrde)

```
/* Make parent invisible */
#parent {
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: scroll;
}

/* Safari and Chrome specific style. Don't need to make parent invisible, because we can style WebKit scrollbars */
#parent:not(*:root) {
  visibility: visible;
}

/* Make Safari and Chrome scrollbar invisible */
#parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Make the child visible */
#child {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: an explanation as to how this works would be appreciated – playing with parent/child visibility to hide the scroll bar is horrible

Comment: @believesInSanta I added comments and codepen to explain better.  I don't agree with your assessment that playing with visibility is a horrible way to hide the scrollbar.  I understand that it is a hack, but the proper way to achieve this effect would be if all the browsers supported a way to style the scrollbar separately like chrome and safari allow.

Comment: I just felt in love with your solution. It perfectly works (used in apps which are design to be used by modern browsers). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

I just thought I'd point out to anyone else reading this question that setting `overflow: hidden` (or overflow-y) on the `body` element didn't hide the scrollbars for me.

I had to use the `html` element.

Comment: I can't remember exactly since it was a couple of months ago, but I believe setting the overflow on the body was working in Chrome, but not Firefox (or vice-versa). Using the HTML tag worked on both, though.

Comment: From memory this may be a quirks mode difference.

Answer (score 7):

If you want scrolling to work, before hiding scrollbars, consider styling
them. Modern versions of OS X and mobile OS's have scrollbars that, while
impractical for grabbing with a mouse, are quite beautiful and neutral.

To hide scrollbars, [a technique by John Kurlak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx) works well except for leaving
Firefox users who don't have touchpads with no way to scroll unless they
have a mouse with a wheel, which they probably do, but even then they can usually
only scroll vertically.

John's technique uses three elements:

- An outer element to mask the scrollbars.
- A middle element to have the scrollbars.
- And a content element to both set the size of the middle element and make
  it have scrollbars.

It must be possible to set the size of the outer and content elements the same
which eliminates using percentages, but I can't think of anything else that
won't work with the right tweaking.

My biggest concern is whether all versions of browsers set scrollbars to make
visible overflowed content visible. I have tested in current browsers, but
not older ones.

Pardon my [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) ;P

```
%size {
    // set width and height
}

.outer {
    // mask scrollbars of child
    overflow: hidden;
    // set mask size
    @extend %size;
    // has absolutely positioned child
    position: relative;
}

.middle {
    // always have scrollbars.
    // don't use auto, it leaves vertical scrollbar showing
    overflow: scroll;
    // without absolute, the vertical scrollbar shows
    position: absolute;
}
// prevent text selection from revealing scrollbar, which it only does on
// some webkit based browsers.
.middle::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.content {
    // push scrollbars behind mask
    @extend %size;
}
```

### Testing

OS X is 10.6.8. Windows is Windows 7.

- Firefox 32.0
  Scrollbars hidden. Arrow keys don't scroll, even after clicking to focus,
  but mouse wheel and two fingers on trackpad do. OS X and Windows.
- Chrome 37.0
  Scrollbars hidden. Arrow keys work after clicking to focus. Mouse wheel
  and trackpad work. OS X and Windows.
- Internet Explorer 11
  Scrollbars hidden. Arrow keys work after clicking to focus. Mouse wheel
  works. Windows.
- Safari 5.1.10
  Scrollbars hidden. Arrow keys work after clicking to focus. Mouse wheel
  and trackpad work. OS X.
- Android 4.4.4 and 4.1.2.
  Scrollbars hidden. Touch scrolling works. Tried in Chrome 37.0, Firefox 
  32.0, and HTMLViewer on 4.4.4 (whatever that is). In HTMLViewer, the page 
  is the size of the masked content and can be scrolled too! Scrolling 
  interacts acceptably with page zooming.

Comment: Unrelated note (as far as the question goes). In this instance, you should be using @extend versus @include. So instead of `@mixin{}`, you'd do `%size{}` then in the css selectors, call `@extend %size;`. Mixins are typically used when your pulling in variables to return an result. Placeholders (aka @extend) are meant for simple repeated code like this - where no "function" is needed.

Comment: I edited to use @extend. The result is probably less understandable to people who don't know SCSS, but well enough.

Answer (score 7):

Copy this CSS code to the customer code for hiding the scroll bar:

```
<style>

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
       display: none;
    }

    #element::-webkit-scrollbar {
       display: none;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

My HTML is like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Add this to your `div` where you want to hide the scrollbar:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 75%; /* This can be any value of your choice */
}
```

And add this to the container

```
.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a WebKit version with some options like **auto hide**, **little version**, scroll **only-y**, or **only-x**:

```
._scrollable{
    @size: 15px;
    @little_version_ratio: 2;
    @scrollbar-bg-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    @scrollbar-handler-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    @scrollbar-handler-color-hover: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    @scrollbar-coner-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        background: none;
        width: @size;
        height: @size;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color:@scrollbar-bg-color;
        border-radius: @size;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: @size;
        background-color:@scrollbar-handler-color;
        &:hover{
            background-color:@scrollbar-handler-color-hover;
        }
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: @scrollbar-coner-color;
    }

    &.little{
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            background: none;
            width: @size / @little_version_ratio;
            height: @size / @little_version_ratio;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            border-radius: @size / @little_version_ratio;
        }
        &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            border-radius: @size / @little_version_ratio;
        }
    }

    &.autoHideScrollbar{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        &:hover{
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            &.only-y{
                overflow-y: scroll !important;
                overflow-x: hidden !important;
            }

            &.only-x{
                overflow-x: scroll !important;
                overflow-y: hidden !important;
            }
        }
    }

    &.only-y:not(.autoHideScrollbar){
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }

    &.only-x:not(.autoHideScrollbar){
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/hicTech/pen/KmKrjb

Answer (score 3):

To disable the vertical scroll bar, just add `overflow-y:hidden;`.

Find more about it: [overflow](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html).

Answer (score 3):

My answer will scroll even when `overflow:hidden;`, using jQuery:

For example, scroll horizontally with the mouse wheel:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

       $("YourSelector").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

          this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
          event.preventDefault();
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Scrolljacking works, but is almost always a poor user experience.

Comment: while this is possible, with a good example, there are massive problems for assistive technology users when you disable scroll and use javascript to handle scrolling. If you do not also set focus to an element every time you scroll for the user, then your AT user will be completely lost. Also, every user has now lost all fine-tuned control over what (s)he sees. Very poor UX to take over scrolling for your user. Besides mousewheel, you also have to handle up/down keys, screen reader rotors, mouse clicks, and touchpad controls. This becomes unwieldy for the developer and awful for the user.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can manipulate it with the `overflow` CSS attribute, but they have limited browser support. One source said it was Internet Explorer 5 (and later), Firefox 1.5 (and later), and Safari 3 (and later) - maybe enough for your purposes.

*[Scrolling, Scrolling, Scrolling](http://www.search-this.com/2008/03/26/scrolling-scrolling-scrolling/)* has a good discussion.

Comment: Good link. It is nice to know how the result on multi browsers. Unfortunately the figure for  a screenshot of the finished results are broken

Answer (score 0):

> *Can CSS be used to hide the scroll bar? How would you do this?*

If you wish to remove vertical (and horizontal) scrollbars from a browser viewport, add:

```
style="position: fixed;"
```

to the `<body>` element.

---

**Javascript:**

```
document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
```

---

**CSS:**

```
body {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Peter's answer:

In case you want to remove the scrollbar from an iframe, you would need to add the styles for removing the scrollbar within the website which is iframed. It is not possible to style elements within an iframe including the scrollbar.

Website which has an iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <body>
   <iframe src="/iframe"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Website which is iframed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>

  <style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }
  .content {
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }

  .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .content {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```