# How to hide scrollbar but still can scroll up/down

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way on how to hide scroll bar and still can scroll up down using mouse or direction keys?

Any one can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/how-to-hide-scrollbar

Comment: Aww, you beat me to it. Did the asker even google though? That was the top result!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what exactly what you want but I like using this plugin for situation like when you want to hide the scrollbar by default and shows up when you hover on the textarea

http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll