# HTML Page displays disabled scrollbar

Tags: html, css

My html page displays empty disabled scrollbar, please see attached screenshot

[image: I am using overflow:hidden but of no use.]

How can i hide this scrollbar completely?

EDIT:

Sorry my mistake, i didn't mentioned that i am using overflow:hidden, but cannot hide this scroll bar.
i am copying my body code below

```
body {
color: #000000;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Try `overflow: hidden`, instead of the x/y directives.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Inspect element and play with the console CSS editor? I suspect it has nothing to do with `body` but with a common most-outer parent container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it has **nothing to do with `overflow` on your `BODY`** element.
Even if you set `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` it's just like using the *shorthand*:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

same as for your `margin`, use only:

```
margin: 0;
// You have also other shorthand variants like:
// margin : top right bottom left;
// margin : topBottom rightLeft;
// margin : top rightLeft bottom;
// helps to keep your CSS file clear as possible.
```

So the probable issue lies in some most outer common parent element like some *wrapper* or *container* that has probably a style set to `overflow: scroll;`
**like in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/aZudaQag/2/edit)**

Comment: I know that there are shorthand for overflow and margin, i copied this css from firebug that is why it is not using shorthands :P, nevertheless my top most element <html> was having overflow scroll, so i removed it and now the issue is resolved..

Comment: @Asad Glad you did it!

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow: hidden;` in your CSS for the body:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or to handle just the verticle scrollbar

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```