# How to disable the scrollbar in skrollr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

How can we disable the `scroll-bar` in skrollr plugin?. I don't see any configuration in their page. Below is fiddle, where the scrolling happens with scroll-bar visible though?.

```
html{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The problem with hiding the scroll-bar is, i am not able to scroll anymore?. Is there a way we can scroll the content with `mouse-wheel` though disabling the `scroll-bars`?

http://jsfiddle.net/5nETU/

Comment: One of the reasons I greated skrollr was because many other frameworks hide the scrollbar or use a custom one...BAD

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser setting. Webkit allows hiding the scrollbar like so (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184693/632736)):

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

It seems unlikely that other browsers will be adopting this feature anytime soon, because it doesn't provide any benefit and the target audience is very narrow.