# Removing scrollbar in responsive media queries

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, media-queries

In my main CSS, I included a vertical scrollbar for a text box because the text is very long. It works and looks great...

```
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
overflow-y: scroll;
```

...except now I've reached my media queries.

I don't know about you, but using a scrollbar on a smartphone is a PITA. I need the entirety of the text to appear without a scrollbar, not just for the scrollbar to disappear.  I've tried all CSS options for "overflow" and "overflow-y" to no avail.

I'm fairly certain I've exhausted all HTML and CSS options, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Look into these solutions: [Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Comment: Go mobile first and only apply your overflow methods in the media queries. I would hesitate to have a scrollbar in the body if at all possible - can you redesign to remove the need?

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow: visible
```

is the default ... but you are better off only defining  your scroll definitions in the media queries for non-mobile defaults going mobile first.

Show us your code if you want more in-depth critique