# Weird css box-sizing in bootstrap 3. How to get rid of horizontal slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 website, which looks well in IE, but Chrome and FF and a bottom slider and small place from the right side is always there  even if I scale to 1 %.

This is something connected to box-sizing property however neither content-box no border-box works. And I cannot find out in inspect element what is there? If you can give me a direction to research - I would be very happy. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Show a live example instead of just a screenshot.

Comment: Looks like the brown stripe is wider than everything else. Are you missing a `.container` or `.container-fluid` somewhere?

Comment: I used to have containers but I removed it searching for this problem. Should I always use container?

Comment: I am sorry, here is the live example, design on the home page is broken I tried to find this problem.
https://torid-fire-6526.firebaseapp.com/#/

Comment: [https://torid-fire-6526.firebaseapp.com/#/](https://torid-fire-6526.firebaseapp.com/#/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without actually visiting the site, but a straight forward fix would be to set set `overflow: hidden;` on the body property as so in your css file:

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can see more information [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Comment: Thank you, yes - overflow-hidden solve the problem, but when you shrink the window size - it does what it suppose to do and cut the sizes, as I have min-height for content.

BUT this is a GREAT direction to research further!!! Thank you!
I used overflow-x:hidden.

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLUTION:

.contentScroller {overflow-y: auto; visibility: hidden;}
.content {visibility: visible;}

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I thought I'd offer my take on the "how to find what's wrong" aspect of the question for those who come after..

- Open up the chrome devtools
- Toggle 'mobile device emulation' - the little phone icon at the very top right of the devtools. The Chrome docs are super informative - I always find something new in there: [Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)
- Shrink the width of your page; if there is any overflow, it will show as a dark grey shadow to the right of the 'emulation window'. Find a page width where this is obvious
- In the Elements tab of devtools, select the top level elements one by one and hit delete, and see if the overflow is eliminated. If not, you can hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to undo the deletion
- When you find that deleting a high level element eliminates the overflow, narrow down to exactly which child element is causing trouble
- When using bootstrap, incorrect nesting of row and column classes (which add and subtract margins / padding) can cause issues
- Check for hardcoded `width`s, `min-width`s, `!important` statements,
- Handy statements to try include `overflow:auto;`, `float:none;`, `position: relative;` - when in doubt: jiggle it!
- Consider adding a breakpoint to refine the responsiveness of the troublesome element

  ```
  <body>
      <header> <-- deleting header may solve the overflow
          <nav>
              <ul> <-- but a child is likely the problem
      <main>
          <section>
      <footer>
          <div>
  ```

Hope that helps someone in future :)