# Scrolling a div over another div

Tags: css

is it possible to see all the content in the top div before the second div scrolls over.

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KyP8L/91/

many thanks for looking.

```
.div-top{
height:auto;
min-height:100%;
width:100%;    
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#ff0;
z-index:500;
}


.div-bottom {
width:100%;    
background:#0ff;
margin-top:100%;
z-index:600;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Not with CSS because it's fixed.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Can you update this question to reflect the conversation with @Naeem? (To start with - - seems like the question he's answered is still not the one you're after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is though not possible with css, you can do it with jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/KyP8L/92/

Just check the scroll, if it reaches top, then assign the z-index(higher) to the `.div-bottom`

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
$(window).scrollTop() ;
    ;

    if($(window).scrollTop()> parseInt($('.div-bottom').css('margin-top')))
    {
        $('.div-bottom').css('z-index','600');
    }else{
         $('.div-bottom').css('z-index','0');
    }

    console.log('top'+$('.div-bottom').css('margin-top'))
  console.log('scroll'+$(window).scrollTop())    

                           });
```

Edit:

> As the OP says in comments what he wants is, to be able to scroll down
>   the top div and then I want the bottom div to scroll over the top div

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KyP8L/108/

Comment: Hey Naeem, Thanks for your answer but unfortunately its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I want to be able to scroll down the top div and then I want the bottom div to scroll over the top div.

Comment: @RicoShaft.. updated the answer, see the jsfiddle included.. did this help you

Comment: Hey Naeem, thanks a lot for your answer. I've also tried overflow:scroll; before but wasn't to happy with the results. There must be a jQuery way but I don't know how.

Comment: you can just hide the scrollbar. you will just need to add some more css and html.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand what you mean by *scrolls over*,

but setting`.div-top{ height:100%}`   
will let you entirely visualize div-top befor getting to the second div.

And still setting `.div-top`  to fixed wouldn't have sense.