# Hiding the scrollbar when it is not moving in CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to get the state of movement in CSS, without JQuery, and use it for hiding the scrollbar?

Comment: you can achieve this by jquery, if mouse position near to scrollbars location then show else hide....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help] . Please let us know what you have tried so far, and where youa re stuck. As it stands, your question will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: `overflow: scroll;` will add a scrollbar only if the screen is small enough

Comment: Can it be done without jquery? Also, I'm not talking about mouse position, but rather hiding it when it isn't scrolling or moving.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable trough jQuery

Scrollevent with jQuery:
https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Scrollevent Stop:
[jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Hide Scrollbar:
[Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

In the end, the could may look like this (not tested):

```
<script>
$( window ).scroll(function() { 
  //Show scrollbar 
  $( "body" ).css( "overflow", "scroll" );

  // Check if we are still scrolling, else hide scrollbar
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    // Scrollevent not happened, hiding Scrollbar
    $( "body" ).css( "overflow", "hidden" );
  }, 250));

});
</script>
```