# Hide scroll bars keeping them work (specific case)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, hide

I need to hide some scroll bars in something like a table.
I have a 5 rows table built with some `div` elements, each row contains a scroll bar for an horizontal scroll.
There is a way for hide them?
I already tryed searching solutions here, but that solutions only work with a single row, or, however, didn't work in my case.

There is the [Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ju265kmn/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page Is this the kind of functionality you're looking for?

Comment: @SamuelHill yes, but I already tried that and didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can hide scroll bars by giving them a style using pseudo selectors:

```
.target::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

This being said it is a big no no in terms of accessibility to change and hide scrollbars, looking at your code you are also using JavaScript to sets widths. Maybe it's worth looking how to re-work your code to completely negotiate these issues.

Comment: It works as i want, but only in Chrome :/ However i'll try to re-work the code, I think is the only way.
Anyway, I used the JS because it is the only way i found for doing an horizontal scroll inside a div, with many divs inside