# Using hidden overflow-x and visible overflow-y width absolute position without scroll

Tags: html, css

I've seen similar questions, have tried one, but this is not worked for my case.

Here is what I want: White and red rect is absolute position. White triggered by hover on red. On this picture `overflow-x` is disabled.

[image: What I want]

Because I need hide red rectangles outside the blue box, I added `overflow-x: hidden`, and it causes y scroll when hovered red rect. Like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 210px;
}
.grid {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 210px;
  background: #333344;
}
.grid__item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #994444;
}
.grid__item .grid__item-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white; 
}
.grid__item:hover .grid__item-hover {
  display: block;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(1) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
  left: 210px;
  top: 5px;
}
.bar {
  height: 100px;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="grid__item-hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="grid__item-hover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Need solution without javascript.

Comment: Not sure you can simply 'hide' the scrollbar. It's there when a scroll is available. You probably could hack it around and maybe have the scrollbar outside of the element (using `overflow:hidden` to hide it), but that's not a very straightforward solution. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your .grid width is greater than your container width?  i.e.

```
container {
  width: 210px;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I am saying .grid width of 100% is greater than container width of 210px, therefore the scroll bar is appearing.  Try making the container width greater than the grid width.

Comment: `100%` means that grid width is exact the as container width. Even if it will be grater, it is does not matter because this is vertical scroll, it depends on height, not width.