# How do I remove the scrollbar of the purecss navbar?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar, yui-pure-css

On my website I use pure.css and the navbar consists of more elements than a small screen can display without scrolling. Therefore a scrollbar appears in that case, which I don't want.
I would like the navbar to stay at the top so that the navbar and the content scrolls simultaneously. When I use position:absolute; everything looks even worse. Also the mobile version of that navbar should still work (on mobile screens scrolling though the navbar should still be possible).

I also tried to deactivate overflow-y, but then, obviously, not every element on the navbar is clickable.

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page#answer-25561646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that navbar and content scroll simultaneously, you shouldn't use `position:fixed`.

- Remove `position:fixed`
- Add `float:left` to menu div
- Add `float:right` to content div

If I misunderstood what you want, the comment made by Marco Valente should be nice.

Comment: Perfect, that was what I was looking for. Now I just need to figure out how to  fill the space below the navbar with the navbar background color.

Comment: You should remove `position: static` from #menu when the menu div have the active class.