# How do I make a scrollable div match the height of the browser minus the footer?

Tags: html, css

I made a replicable version of what I am doing on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deoa0cyo/1/

I have in the html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <img class="top-img" src="http://www.reunitingall.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Cat-Sun-God-640x388.jpg" />
    <h3>
      Group Cats
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <ul>
      <li>one cat</li>
      <li>two cats</li>
      <li>green cats</li>
      <li>blue cats</li>
      <li>one cat</li>
      <li>two cats</li>
      <li>green cats</li>
      <li>blue cats</li>
      <li>one cat</li>
      <li>two cats</li>
      <li>green cats</li>
      <li>blue cats</li>
      <li>one cat</li>
      <li>two cats</li>
      <li>green cats</li>
      <li>blue cats</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  footer text! Wooohoooo
</footer>
```

but the footer overlaps with my bottom div. I want the bottom div to be as big as possible, without overlapping my floating footer. How can I make this happen?

Comment: `.bottom{height: calc(100% - 50px)}`

Comment: you can use `vw` in styles (minus the height of your footer) 
e.g. say your footer is `1vh` then your height of `div` can be `90vh`

Comment: How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/Nekomajin42/Ljf8mk9d/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do multiple things. In the example you gave us, the best thing to do is this:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpospxe2/)

This adds a `padding-bottom: 50px` to .container. The amount of padding should be the same as as the height of the footer. This also adds a `background-color: white` to the footer, and white should of course be the color that would've been behind the text.

When this is not possible you can set the height of .container to `calc(100vh - 50px)` And add `overflow-y: scroll`. You will have scrollbars at the side of .container. Also note that calc() [will not work on all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc()).

You can hide the scrollbars using the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

.footer
{ transform:translate(x,y);

}

example

.footer{
transform:translate(500px,700px)
}

Comment: The correct value to use would be (0px, 50px), but since the element is fixed to the bottom this moves it off-screen.

Comment: It just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow of `body` to `hidden` and set overflow on container div. Also set height of container div to `100% - footerHeight`

I have made these changes plus some minor changes. Check if you are looking for something like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/h0W0NxFPkNl4HtUhlgDP?p=preview