# How to hide scrollbar in Chromium when static , but show when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to hide the scrollbar when static, but show when scrolling?

I tried the following css based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page), but the scrollbar doesn't show up during scrolling.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; 
}
```

There is another [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4a07v0/css_vertical_scrollbar_hidden_when_page_is_static/) achieving similar feature on Firefox, but not Chromium.

It would be best if this feature can be achieved by css.

Comment: You can't add an "onscroll" listener in pure CSS like in JS, and there aren't any scroll-pseudoclasses like `:hover` so you'll have to use JS.

Comment: Did you make any progress with your issue?

Comment: That works! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a timer to show the scrollbar, and on scroll event reset the timer and show the scrollbar:

```
var el = document.body; // you can use the following code on any element
var showScrollbarTimeout = 0; // track the timeout function so that we can reset it later

function hideScroll () { el.style.overflow = "hidden"; }
function showScroll () { el.style.overflow = "visible"; }

function hideLater () { showScrollbarTimeout = setTimeout(hideScroll, 1000); }

hideLater();

el.onscroll = function () {
    clearTimeout(showScrollbarTimeout);
    showScroll();
    hideLater();
}
```