# Hide Horizontal Scroll Bar but make data scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, less

I want to make image scroller where image can be scrolled horizontally but dont want horizontal scroll bar to be visible while scrolling. 
Below is the link to my codepen..

http://codepen.io/rajMrPerfect/pen/PWewRM?editors=0100

```
<div class="scroll">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>

.scroll {
    height: 180px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  
    img {
        margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184693/2232127

Comment: How do you want it scrolled if there is no scrollbar?

Comment: I want to scroll it as the normal scroller but hide the scroll bar.

Comment: so what would the user interaction be? mousewheel? dragging an invisible scrollbar?

Comment: it would be some what like dragging an invisible scrollbar

Comment: maybe something like this? http://asvd.github.io/dragscroll/

Comment: In best words i need a mousewhel

Comment: yes right but without scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.scroll {
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; 
}

img {
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://asvd.github.io/dragscroll/dragscroll.js"></script>
<div class="scroll  horizontal dragscroll">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img      src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img     src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img  src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; 
}

img {
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://asvd.github.io/dragscroll/dragscroll.js"></script>
<div class="scroll  horizontal dragscroll">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img      src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img     src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img  src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an inivisble scrollbar you will need some javascript code to handle the scrolling.

I would use: https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll

Then:

```css
.scroll {
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; 
}

img {
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://asvd.github.io/dragscroll/dragscroll.js"></script>
<div class="scroll  horizontal dragscroll">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img      src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img     src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img  src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

In the above examples, the items can be scrolled on "mouse click and drag" but you can extend the scroll by binding to the mousewheel.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for Chrome

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
    *::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
```

Another Solution would be (not really optimal)

```
-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: No good for cross browser though: http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar, only works really in chrome