# How to hide the scroll bar and with the content ramaining scrollable?

Tags: html, css, printing, scrollbar, overflow

I want to print my html page into a PDF file, but don't want the scroll bar showing there in the PDF file. And my page have a scrollable body, so if I set this:

```
* {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The body will be incomplete in the final pdf file.
So if there is a way just prevent the scrollbar from showing but the content still scrollable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari).  That rule is:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in IE 10+.  That rule is:

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

There used to be a CSS rule that could hide scrollbars in Firefox, but it has since been deprecated.  That rule was:

```
.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set display of scrollbar to none by:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide all the scrollbars without disabling scrolling.

Edit: this only  works on chrome, for a better explanation you can check this answer [Hidding Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25561646/7225022)

Comment: This is the Perfect way. Display to none.