# Hide Vertical Scrollbar in Chrome while printing

Tags: javascript, css

How can I remove the scrollbar while I print report in Chrome Browser.
Here is my code:

```
<style>
     @media print {
         @page {
             size: A4 portrait;
             margin:1cm;
         }
</style>
```

Here is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I found:

```
 @media print{
            @page {
                size: A4 portrait;
                margin:1cm;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` is the css property you are looking for. It removes the scrollbar and removes overflowing content. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

```
<style>
     @media print{
         @page {
             size: A4 portrait;
             margin:1cm;
             overflow: hidden;
            }
     }
</style>
```

Or try to set the overflow hidden without depending on the media query:

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
```

If this does not help for printing, maybe have a look at the answer of following question: [How to hide the scroll bar and with the content ramaining scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268436/how-to-hide-the-scroll-bar-and-with-the-content-ramaining-scrollable)

As mentioned there you could try to set the width of the scrollbar to zero for webkit browsers.

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268436/how-to-hide-the-scroll-bar-and-with-the-content-ramaining-scrollable

Comment: I found the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268436/how-to-hide-the-scroll-bar-and-with-the-content-ramaining-scrollable.