# Horizontal scrolling without displaying bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display list of menu by scrolling horizontally. So I have written code as:

```
.sub-menu {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.menu.navbar-nav li{
    width: 22%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

But it is showing a bar horizontally but I want to disappear it. Please see the [image].

Could you tell me someone how can I remove it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobile-menu temp-mobile-menu visible-xs">
<div class="sub-menu">
    <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav" id="">
        <li class="active"><a href="/bn" class="first leaf home active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bn/tonic-doctor" class="leaf doctor">Doctor</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bn/tonic-benefits" class="leaf benefits">Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bn/packages" class="leaf packages">Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bn/health-topics" style="swiper-slide" class="last leaf স্বাস্থ্য-প্রসঙ্গ">স্বাস্থ্য প্রসঙ্গ</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
</div>
```

**Updated CSS**

```
.mobile-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sub-menu {
  min-height: 44px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.menu.navbar-nav li {
 width: 22%;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Comment: I would point you in particular to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25561646/2117156)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow-x: scroll;` means that your horizontal scroll bar is visible.

If you want to remove it, use `overflow-x: hidden;`

By the way, if you want both horizontal and vertical scrollers to be hidden, just use: `overflow: hidden;`

If you want to hide the scrollbar but **keep scrolling capabilities**, add a `div` with a `CSS class` called `maindiv` above your `sub-menu` element and use:

```
.maindiv{       
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sub-menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: I want to hide bar keeping horizontal scrolling

Comment: I have done as you said but it does not work. I have added the html in my question.

Comment: See updated answer - try adding `padding-bottom:20px;`

Comment: Also make sure you are refreshing the page properly and not from cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137332/discussion-between-streetcoder-and-koby-douek).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `overflow-x: scroll;` to `overflow-x: hidden;` in your `.sub-menu` class

EDIT:
Add this class to CSS file:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
width: 0px; /* remove scrollbar space */ 
background: transparent; /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */ 
}
```

[Working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/om0q05cy/)

Comment: I want to hide bar keeping horizontal scrolling

Comment: If you cannot solve with @Koby Douek answer, can you okease show also html code by updating your answer?

Comment: For Firefox there are moz-webkits and for Microsoft moz-webkits I thik