# CSS hide scroll bar, but have element scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have this element called items and the content inside the element is longer
than the element height, I want to make it scrollable but hide the scroll bar,
how would I do that?

```html
<div class="left-side">
    <div
      class="items"
      style="display:block;width: 94%;margin: 0 auto;overflow: hidden;"
    >
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.left-side {
    height: 878px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 1470px;
}
```

I tried setting the left-side class overflow to auto, but that didn't do
anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Comment: "*[..]I want to make it scrollable but hide the scroll bar*" -- That would be horrible! Scrollbars have a purpose, and that purpose is to scroll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Yes, @Abhitalks is correct: that would break the usability of the page.Do hide the scrollbar if it is not needed; don't hide it if there is more content below the fold. https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-scrollbars/

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can hide it:

```
html {
  overflow:   scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}
```

For further information, see: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: you could hide it, but it would be very poor usability.

Comment: Here's a good complete reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

Comment: Even in the provided link it states this doesn't work in FF or IE

Comment: This only works on desktop chrome. It doesn't work on any other browser I've tested on.

Comment: why is ```background: transparent;``` needed? Wouldn't ```width: 0``` be enough?

Comment: for horizontal scrollbar, it's pretty obvious but we'd set `height: 0;`

Comment: Correct, `width: 0` is enough to hide a vertical scrollbar and `height: 0` to hide a horizontal one

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none
}

This would be much better

Comment: The classic "oh no, no, you should never do that".  Some people think that if they can't think of a use for something, one doesn't exist

Answer (score 89):

I combined a couple of different answers in SO into the following snippet,
which should work on all, if not most, modern browsers I believe.  All you
have to do is add the CSS class `.disable-scrollbars` onto the element you wish
to apply this to.

```css
.disable-scrollbars::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent; /* Chrome/Safari/Webkit */
  width: 0px;
}
    
.disable-scrollbars {
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE 10+ */
}
```

And if you want to use SCSS/SASS:

```css
.disable-scrollbars {
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE 10+ */

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: transparent; /* Chrome/Safari/Webkit */
    width: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: To have this rule apply to all children, `.disable-scrollbars * {` and `.disable-scrollbars *::-webkit-scrollbar {`

Comment: add `height: 0;` next to width to also catch horizontal scrollbars

Answer (score 13):

Hope this helps

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
html {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Similar to Kiloumap L'artélon's answer,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none;
}
```

works too

Comment: This only works on desktop chrome. It doesn't work on any other browser I've tested on.

Comment: `width: 0;` seems to hide the horizontal scrollbar, but leaves a weird empty gap on Chrome desktop 83.  `display: none;` does not have this issue. I threw in both just to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

work on all major browsers

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can hide it on specific div usig class:

```html
<div class="hide-scroll"></div>
```

```css
.hide-scroll{
    overflow: scroll;
}

.hide-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
    width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [SlimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) plugin to make a div scrollable even if it is set to `overflow: hidden;`(i.e. scrollbar hidden).

You can also control touch scroll as well as the scroll speed using this plugin.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This plugin doesn't even work on its own demo page, so it's unlikely to be a good solution...

Answer (score 1):

if you use sass, you can try this

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}
```

Comment: You haven't put any styles within this so this isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Make sure that you put it on root, so it should work with html/body part.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to get rid of the scrollbar, split the information up into two separate pages.

[Usability guidelines on scrollbars by Jakob Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-scrollbars/):

> There are five essential usability guidelines for scrolling and scrollbars:
>
> - Offer a scrollbar if an area has scrolling content. Don't rely on
>     auto-scrolling or on dragging, which people might not notice.
> - Hide
>     scrollbars if all content is visible. If people see a scrollbar, they
>     assume there's additional content and will be frustrated if they can't
>     scroll.
> - Comply with GUI standards and use scrollbars that look like
>     scrollbars.
> - Avoid horizontal scrolling on Web pages and minimize it
>     elsewhere.
> - Display all important information above the fold. Users
>     often decide whether to stay or leave based on what they can see
>     without scrolling. Plus they only allocate 20% of their attention
>     below the fold.

To make your scrollbar only visible when it is needed (i.e. when there is content to scroll down to), use `overflow: auto`.

Comment: This is nice and sensible, but sometimes you _really_ want to do things that sound strange without the context. For example, if you have a complex table component with one or more splitter, and the sections are scroll-synced, you only want the scrollbar on one section because it's obvious for the user that the whole thing is scrollable as one unit and individual scrollbars only add confusion.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: You effectively told the OP that what he is trying to do is wrong. There are cases where it is right (a carousel is the most common one). In the case of a carousel, there is some other UI element that indicates the drag capability (arrows rendered by the application and/or position dots).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css and the job is done...

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
body {
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```