# How to remove vertical bar from print preview

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to print a bootstrap modal in chrome but I see always I press the print button and preview the print, the preview shows this vertical bar.
How can I remove this vertical bar in print preview. I don't know why this is showing. There is no vertical bar in the actual bootstrap modal which I am printing.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here is the html coding:

```
<style>
.str td{
    padding-top:1px !important;
    padding-bottom:1px !important;
}
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td{padding: 5px;}
</style>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg no-modal-header">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <i class="fa fa-2x">×</i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default no-print pull-right" style="margin-right:15px;" onclick="window.print();">
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i> <?= lang('print'); ?></button>
                        <?php if ($logo) {
    ?>
            <div class="text-cente no-print" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                <img src="<?= base_url() . 'assets/uploads/logos/' . $biller->logo; ?>"
                    alt="<?= $biller->company && $biller->company != '-' ? $biller->company : $biller->name; ?>">
            </div>
            <?php
} ?>
                        <div class="well well-sm no-print">
                <div class="row bold">
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                         <p class="bold">
                            <?= lang('date'); ?>: <?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->date); ?><br>
                            <?= lang('ref'); ?>: <?= $inv->reference_no; ?><br>
                            <?php if (!empty($inv->return_sale_ref)) {
        echo lang('return_ref') . ': ' . $inv->return_sale_ref;
        if ($inv->return_id) {
            echo ' <a data-target="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal" href="' . admin_url('sales/modal_view/' . $inv->return_id) . '"><i class="fa fa-external-link no-print"></i></a><br>';
        } else {
            echo '<br>';
        }
    } ?>
                            <?= lang('sale_status'); ?>: <?= lang($inv->sale_status); ?><br>
                            <?= lang('payment_status'); ?>: <?= lang($inv->payment_status); ?><br>
                            <?= $inv->payment_method ? lang('payment_method') . ': ' . lang($inv->payment_method) : ''; ?>
                            <?php
                        if ($inv->payment_method == 'cod' || $inv->payment_method == 'bank' && $inv->attachment) {
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?= admin_url('welcome/download/' . $inv->attachment) ?>"
                                title="<?= lang('attachment') ?>" class="tip">
                                <i class="fa fa-chain"></i>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                            <?php if ($inv->payment_status != 'paid' && $inv->due_date) {
                            echo '<br>' . lang('due_date') . ': ' . $this->sma->hrsd($inv->due_date);
                        } ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">

                <?php if ($Settings->invoice_view == 1) {
                            ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <h1><?= lang('tax_invoice'); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php
                        } ?>


            </div>
            <?php
                    $col = $Settings->indian_gst ? 5 : 4;
                    if ($Settings->product_discount && $inv->product_discount != 0) {
                        $col++;
                    }
                    if ($Settings->tax1 && $inv->product_tax > 0) {
                        $col++;
                    }
                    if ($Settings->product_discount && $inv->product_discount != 0 && $Settings->tax1 && $inv->product_tax > 0) {
                        $tcol = $col - 2;
                    } elseif ($Settings->product_discount && $inv->product_discount != 0) {
                        $tcol = $col - 1;
                    } elseif ($Settings->tax1 && $inv->product_tax > 0) {
                        $tcol = $col - 1;
                    } else {
                        $tcol = $col;
                    }
                    
                    
                ?>

             <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <?php if ($Settings->invoice_view == 1) {
                            ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <h1><?= lang('tax_invoice'); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                <?php
                        } ?>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                           <?php echo $this->lang->line('to'); ?>:
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 pull-left" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                            <strong>
                                <p><small><?= $customer->company && $customer->company != '-' ? $customer->company : $customer->name; ?></small></p>
                    <?= $customer->company                              && $customer->company != '-' ? '' : 'Attn: ' . $customer->name ?></strong></p>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                            <small>
                           <?php if ($customer->vat_no != '-' && $customer->vat_no != '') {
                        echo '<br>' . lang('vat_no') . ': ' . $customer->vat_no;
                    }
                    if ($customer->gst_no != '-' && $customer->gst_no != '') {

                        echo '<br>' . lang('gst_no') . ': ' . $customer->gst_no;
                    }
                    if ($customer->cf1 != '-' && $customer->cf1 != '') {

                        echo lang('ccf1') . ': ' . $customer->cf1;
                    }
                    if ($customer->cf2 != '-' && $customer->cf2 != '') {

                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf2') . ': ' . $customer->cf2;
                    }
                    if ($customer->cf3 != '-' && $customer->cf3 != '') {

                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf3') . ': ' . $customer->cf3;
                    }
                    if ($customer->cf4 != '-' && $customer->cf4 != '') {

                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf4') . ': ' . $customer->cf4;
                    }
                    if ($customer->cf5 != '-' && $customer->cf5 != '') { 

                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf5') . ': ' . $customer->cf5;
                    }
                    if ($customer->cf6 != '-' && $customer->cf6 != '') {

                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf6') . ': ' . $customer->cf6;
                    }
                    ?>
                         </small> 
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <?php
                    echo '<small>'.$customer->address . '<br>' . $customer->city . ' ' . $customer->postal_code . ' ' . $customer->state . '<br>' . $customer->country;
                        
                         ?>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <small><?php echo lang('tel') . ': ' . $customer->phone . '<br>' . lang('email') . ': ' . $customer->email;
                    ?></small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped print-table order-table" style="page-break-inside:auto">
                 <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"><small>SALES&nbsp;PERSON</small></th>
                        <th colspan="2"><small>REFERENCE&nbsp;NO</small></th>
                        <th colspan="2"><small>INVOICE&nbsp;DATE</small></th>
                        <th colspan="2"><small>PAID&nbsp;BY</small></th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><small><?=$created_by->first_name?></small></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><small><?=$inv->reference_no?></small></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><small><?=$this->sma->hrld($inv->date)?></small></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><small><?=$payments?></small></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><small>NO</small></th>
                        <th><small>DESCRIPTION</small></th>
                        <th><small>QTY</small></th>
                        <th><small>UNIT</small></th>
                        <th><small>SUB&nbsp;TOTAL</small></th>
                        <th><small>%</small></th>
                        <th class="text-right"><small>TOTAL</small></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $r = 1;
                    
                    if($rows){
                        foreach ($rows as $row):
                        
                    ?>
                    <tr class="str" style="<?php if($r == 9){ echo 'page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;';  } ?>" >
                            <td class="std"><small><?=$r?></small></td>
                            <td class="std"><small><?=$row->product_name?></small></td>
                            <td class="std"><small><?=$this->sma->formatQuantity($row->unit_quantity)?></small></td>
                            <td class="std"><small><?=number_format((float)$row->unit_price + $row->item_discount, 2, '.', '')?></small>
                            </td>
                            <td class="std"><small><?=number_format((float)($row->unit_price)*($row->unit_quantity), 2, '.', '')?></small>
                            </td>
                            <td class="std"><small><?=number_format((float)$row->item_discount, 2, '.', '')?></small></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($row->subtotal)?></small></td>

                        </tr>



                        <?php
                        $r++;
                        
                        
                        
                    endforeach;
                    }
                    if ($return_rows) {
                        echo '<tr class="warning"><td colspan="100%" class="no-border"><strong>' . lang('returned_items') . '</strong></td></tr>';
                        foreach ($return_rows as $row):
                        ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><small><?=$r?></small></td>
                            <td><small><?=$row->product_name?></small></td>
                            <td><small><?=$this->sma->formatQuantity($row->unit_quantity)?></small></td>
                            <td><small><?=number_format((float)$row->unit_price + $row->item_discount, 2, '.', '')?></small>
                            </td>
                            <td><small><?=number_format((float)($row->unit_price)*($row->unit_quantity), 2, '.', '')?></small>
                            </td>
                            <td><small><?=number_format((float)$row->item_discount, 2, '.', '')?></small></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($row->subtotal)?></small></td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            $r++;
                        endforeach;
                    }
                    ?>
                     
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                   <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small><?=lang('total');?></small></th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                            <small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? (($inv->total + $inv->product_tax) + ($return_sale->total + $return_sale->product_tax)) : ($inv->total + $inv->product_tax));?></small>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        if ($inv->order_tax != 0) {
                            echo '<tr><th colspan="6><small>' . lang('tax') . '</th><th class="text-right"colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->order_tax + $return_sale->order_tax) : $inv->order_tax) . '</small></th></tr>';
                        }
                        if ($inv->order_discount != 0) {
                            echo '<tr><th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>' . lang('order_discount') . '</small></th><th class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->order_discount + $return_sale->order_discount) : $inv->order_discount) . '</small></th></tr>';
                        }

                        if ($inv->shipping != 0) {
                            echo '<tr><th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>' . lang('shipping') . '</th><th class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($inv->shipping) . '</small></th></tr>';
                        }

                        if ($return_sale) {
                            if ($return_sale->surcharge != 0) {
                                echo '<tr><th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>' . lang('return_surcharge') . '</small></th><th class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale->surcharge) . '</small></th></tr>';
                            }
                        }

                        if ($Settings->indian_gst) {
                            if ($inv->cgst > 0) {
                                $cgst = $return_sale ? $inv->cgst + $return_sale->cgst : $inv->cgst;
                                echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><small>' . lang('cgst') . '</small></td><td class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . ($Settings->format_gst ? $this->sma->formatMoney($cgst) : $cgst) . '</small></td></tr>';
                            }
                            if ($inv->sgst > 0) {
                                $sgst = $return_sale ? $inv->sgst + $return_sale->sgst : $inv->sgst;
                                echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><small>' . lang('sgst') . '</small></td><td class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . ($Settings->format_gst ? $this->sma->formatMoney($sgst) : $sgst) . '</small></td></tr>';
                            }
                            if ($inv->igst > 0) {
                                $igst = $return_sale ? $inv->igst + $return_sale->igst : $inv->igst;
                                echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><small>' . lang('igst') . '</small></td><td class="text-right" colspan="6"><small>' . ($Settings->format_gst ? $this->sma->formatMoney($igst) : $igst) . '</small></td></tr>';
                            }
                        }

                        if ($pos_settings->rounding || $inv->rounding != 0) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small><?=lang('rounding'); ?></small></th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                                <small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($inv->rounding); ?></small></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small><?=lang('grand_total'); ?></small></th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                                <small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? (($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding) + $return_sale->grand_total) : ($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding)); ?></small>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small><?=lang('grand_total'); ?></small></th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                                <small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->grand_total + $return_sale->grand_total) : $inv->grand_total); ?></small>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        if ($inv->paid < ($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding)) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small><?=lang('paid_amount'); ?></small></th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                                <small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->paid + $return_sale->paid) : $inv->paid); ?></small>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>Due Amount</small></th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                                <small><?=$this->sma->formatMoney(($return_sale ? (($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding) + $return_sale->grand_total) : ($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding)) - ($return_sale ? ($inv->paid + $return_sale->paid) : $inv->paid)); ?></small>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        } ?>
                         <td colspan='8'>
                            <strong><small>Please Note : Any deposit balances are due prior to the above Confirmed
                                    Product Delivery Date</small></strong>
                            <br>
                            <small>All goods remain the property of Arcadia Traders untill paid in full.</small>
                            <br>
                            <small>- Please use invoice number as reference for all payments.</small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                </table>
            </div>

            <?= $Settings->invoice_view > 0 ? $this->gst->summary($rows, $return_rows, ($return_sale ? $inv->product_tax + $return_sale->product_tax : $inv->product_tax)) : ''; ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <?php
                        if ($inv->note || $inv->note != '') {
                            ?>
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <p class="bold"><?= lang('note'); ?>:</p>
                        <div><?= $this->sma->decode_html($inv->note); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                        if ($inv->staff_note || $inv->staff_note != '') {
                            ?>
                    <div class="well well-sm staff_note">
                        <p class="bold"><?= lang('staff_note'); ?>:</p>
                        <div><?= $this->sma->decode_html($inv->staff_note); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        } ?>
                </div>

                <?php if ($customer->award_points != 0 && $Settings->each_spent > 0) {
                            ?>
                <div class="col-xs-5 pull-left">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <?=
                        '<p>' . lang('this_sale') . ': ' . floor(($inv->grand_total / $Settings->each_spent) * $Settings->ca_point)
                        . '<br>' .
                        lang('total') . ' ' . lang('award_points') . ': ' . $customer->award_points . '</p>'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                        } ?>
                

                <div class="order_barcodes no-print">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div style="max-width:200px; padding-top:7px;">
                                        <img src="<?= admin_url('misc/barcode/' . $this->sma->base64url_encode($inv->reference_no) . '/code128/74/0/1'); ?>"
                                            alt="<?= $inv->reference_no; ?>" class="bcimg">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <div style="max-width:70px">
                                        <?= $this->sma->qrcode('link', urlencode(admin_url('sales/view/' . $inv->id)), 2); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <br>



                </div>



                <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right no-print">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <p>
                            <?= lang('created_by'); ?>:
                            <?= $inv->created_by ? $created_by->first_name . ' ' . $created_by->last_name : $customer->name; ?>
                            <br>
                            <?= lang('date'); ?>: <?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->date); ?>
                        </p>
                        <?php if ($inv->updated_by) {
                            ?>
                        <p>
                            <?= lang('updated_by'); ?>:
                            <?= $updated_by->first_name . ' ' . $updated_by->last_name; ?><br>
                            <?= lang('update_at'); ?>: <?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->updated_at); ?>
                        </p>
                        <?php
                        } ?>
                                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php if (!$Supplier || !$Customer) {
                            ?>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="<?= admin_url('sales/add_payment/' . $inv->id) ?>" class="tip btn btn-primary"
                            title="<?= lang('add_payment') ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                            <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('payment') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="<?= admin_url('sales/add_delivery/' . $inv->id) ?>" class="tip btn btn-primary"
                            title="<?= lang('add_delivery') ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('delivery') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($inv->attachment) {
                                ?>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="<?= admin_url('welcome/download/' . $inv->attachment) ?>" class="tip btn btn-primary"
                            title="<?= lang('attachment') ?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-chain"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('attachment') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                            } ?>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="<?= admin_url('sales/email/' . $inv->id) ?>" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#myModal2" class="tip btn btn-primary" title="<?= lang('email') ?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('email') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="<?= admin_url('sales/pdf/' . $inv->id) ?>" class="tip btn btn-primary"
                            title="<?= lang('download_pdf') ?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('pdf') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (!$inv->sale_id) {
                                ?>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="<?= admin_url('sales/edit/' . $inv->id) ?>" class="tip btn btn-warning sledit"
                            title="<?= lang('edit') ?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('edit') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="#" class="tip btn btn-danger bpo"
                            title="<b><?= $this->lang->line('delete_sale') ?></b>"
                            data-content="<div style='width:150px;'><p><?= lang('r_u_sure') ?></p><a class='btn btn-danger' href='<?= admin_url('sales/delete/' . $inv->id) ?>'><?= lang('i_m_sure') ?></a> <button class='btn bpo-close'><?= lang('no') ?></button></div>"
                            data-html="true" data-placement="top">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><?= lang('delete') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                            } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                        } ?>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tip').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't expect us to help if you don't provide how you did it. Include HTML, CSS etc,.

Comment: Css is split in different files but plz let me know if css is needed too

Answer (score 1):

I'm no sure of what exactly your problem is, but you can try adding `style="overflow: hidden;"` at the beginning (at `str`) and maybe that solves the problem.

Comment: I don't have any section in my html, Can you exactly tell me where should I add this?

Comment: You mean I need to do this? 
.str{
overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: Didn't succeed using your answer. Tried both these:
.str{ overflow: hidden;}
.str td {overflow: hidden;}

Comment: Do u have `<body>`? You can try put it there

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide this `scroll bar` by adding this `css` property in your style tag only if your website do not have scrolling behaviour

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
```

But if you website does have scrolling behaviour and you just want to remove this `scroll bar` from printing document then you can use add these `css` proeprties in your style tag

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  /* make scrollbar transparent */
```

[actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186015/css-hide-scroll-bar-but-have-element-scrollable/43186311)

Comment: The second solution is completely removing scroll bar from the site. I only want to remove from the print

Comment: To make it work only on print, I did this:
@media print {
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
        }

Comment: @TayyabYasin so you just add this css property to your `print` that's great!, solving problem by your own is absolutely brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.print() and hide everything except the modal. The scroll bars won’t be there using this method.