# Cannot find a way to turn off scrollbars on home page

Tags: html

Would someone be able to look at this page, [www.sermanengineering.com](http://www.sermanengineering.com) and tell me what I am missing? I know the code is a mess but I've spent two hours trying to turn off the scrollbars to no avail. I've tried using `overflow:hidden` but it is not working. Does it have something to do with the java slider?

Comment: add `overflow: hidden` to body tag in CSS

Comment: I have had a quick look at your css and you need the overflow:hidden tag on your body element

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your head tag:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
HTML { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
</STYLE>
```

This *should* prevent the page from scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the following problems in your code..

1. `Div #container height: 725px`
2. `Div #wn has top attribute:300px`

The values you entered is making the total height of the page greater than the screen available height so scrollbars are getting enabled.Try changing those values. Always try to avoid hardcoding the values of height and top attributes. `screen.availHeight` will give the available height of the screen. use this value to assign the height for your elements accordingly

Comment: Thank you but when I make the container larger to be sure there is enough room for the #wn div then the scrollbars do not go away. Anyway, I'm mainly concerned with the horizontal scrollbar since it allows you to scroll through the slider images which looks terrible.

Comment: You can also use 100vh or 100vw, this takes the available height or width in percentages by looking at the available viewport space

Answer (score 0):

Try these options inside your css script:

```
html, body {margin: 0!important; height: 100%!important;overflow: hidden!important;}
```

And these inside your html script:

```
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden!important;">
```

Otherwise you could check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184693/7862006

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got it working but am not sure which of the edits did the trick. I was previewing my page in Dreamweaver live view which shows the scroll bars but when I finally checked in chrome they were gone. I appreciate everyones help.

Comment: Perhaps its a dreamweaver thing, otherwise try stripping out 1 by 1 till you get bars again, but np at all