# How auto hide scrollbar on windows browser

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

I have several elements with `overflow: auto`. It works nice. On macOS, scrollbars are automatically hidden when the user is not scrolling and appear on scroll.

On windows and on any browsers scrollbars are always visible. It makes an ugly rendering.

So how can I auto hide scrollbars on every OS and every browser when the user is not scrolling?

I know there is a lot of similar question but I haven't found a suitable answer

Comment: I think this depends on how the Browser handles scrollbars, and there is not much you can do about it. The only real crossbrowser solution would be to write your own scrollbars with JS.

Comment: Does this give you something you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3296644/125981

Answer (score 4):

[perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) is a

> Minimalistic but perfect custom scrollbar plugin

It works with almost every web browser, including Internet Explorer.

Comment: Nice but I would like to find something without have to use js

Answer (score 4):

I found something ! I've never thought it could be so simple :

```
.my-elem {
  overflow: hidden
} 

.my-elem:hover {
  overflow: auto
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I assume you've tested this sollution across a few browsers - so, in your experience, is scroll position of div maintained on `onmouseleave` generally?

Comment: didn't work for me. Hovering doesn't change the overflow property basically. Tried it on chrome on windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

The code above hides both horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

Since every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, you may have to do a **CSS Reset** that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline. Then your HTML will appear the same on all browsers.

You can also **Normalize. Normalize.css** preserves useful defaults rather than "unstyling" everything.