# Setting the position of a Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css

In my website I have two main `divs` - one for the banner at the top, and one for the main content. They both contain inner elements like `imgs`, `iframes` etc. but I don't think this is important for my problem which is: **how can I make the scroll bar for the main content not overlap the banner?**

If it helps, you can view the source for my [actual website](http://joeiddon.me) on [my github](http://github.com/roadkillcat/roadkillcat.github.io). But to save wasting time looking, I've wrote a small snippet in `html` which demonstrates this issue:

```js
document.getElementById("someText").innerText = "this is some content ".replace(/ /g, '\n').repeat(15);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: teal;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  postion: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="header">
header
</div>

<div id="main">
<pre id="someText"></pre>
</div>

</body>
```

It may be hard to see, in the snippet here on `SO` but the `scroll bar` on the right overlaps the banner and I what I want is for it to stop when it reaches the banner.

I have tried (in the `CSS`) setting the `overflow` of the body to `hidden` as this is the `scroll bar` overlapping the banner, but this just removes it entirely so I can't scroll - so clearly not what I am looking for...

I have also tried setting the `overflow-y` of the `main` `div` to `scroll`, but this does not work as a `bar` does appear where I want it, but it is `grayed-out` so not usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/3gvowvag/1/

Your HTML and JS stays the same. For your CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
 }

#header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: teal;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

So the changes are basically to give your `html, body` a `overflow-y: hidden` and your `#main` a `max-height` and `width` of `100%` as well as `overflow-y: scroll`.

This basically does what you want - though I wouldn't be 100% confident about setting up the page like that. Absolute positioning and offsetting via pixels is a bit oldschool, also setting the overflow-y to hidden for html/body, not exactly sure how those things will behave in the long term. But pretty hard to fully think of this without further context.

P.S.: awesome cat!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `overflow-y: hidden;` to the body (take a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)) and then apply `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `#main` div.

```js
document.getElementById("someText").innerText = "this is some content ".replace(/ /g, '\n').repeat(30);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: teal;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  postion: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="header">
header
</div>

<div id="main">
<pre id="someText"></pre>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: If you re-read the bottom of my question, you can see I had already tried that and it doesn't work.. run your code snippet and you will see the scroll bar is "grayed-out".

Comment: Weird thing... I tried it in [another context](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/f68a745bd50b8f6fb964a48fedc70f5b) and it worked. I presumed that the stackoverflow code snippet app was not rendering it correctly, I couldn't find another explanation. Maybe I'm missing something obvious... Please let me know if you figure out. Cheers!

Comment: konrad above solved it, you need to **set the height of the main div** and then giving it an `overflow` for it to work

Comment: Sure, thanks! Just as I predicted, I was missing a big obvious thing :D

Answer (score 0):

You might find this easier with a flexbox layout. Maybe something like this. As example set the overflow to auto if you don't want to see the greyed out scroll bar

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
       header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       content
       content
       content
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
     background:blue;
     height: 100vw;
 }

 .header{
      height:100px;
      background-color:pink
  }

  .content{
      background:green;
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow:scroll;
  }
```