# How to hide a specific scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

This (red arrow) scrollbars showed up in my app because I'm using `redux-lazy-scroll` and I have a question: is it possible to hide that particular scrollbar?

I tried

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

But it hides all scrollbars (that green arrow one too) and I don't want that.

[image]

Any ideas how to crack it?

And sorry but I don't know how to reproduce this strange additional scrollbars behavior of `redux-lazy-scroll` with `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`.

[image]

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Have you taken a look here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because I want to hide only two scrollbars of three, and other solutions hide every scrollbar in my app...

Comment: You need to give overflow:hide; of container of that product elements...not the main scrollbar

Comment: Thank you @yjs

I used chrome dev inspector and found that redux-lazy-scroll created `redux-lazy-scroll` div.

So I used:

    .redux-lazy-scroll {
      overflow: hidden !important;
    }

And it worked and infinite scrolling is still working!