# Hide scrollbar but still scrollable in css

Tags: css

Hide scrollbar but still scrollable in CSS

i try `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` this is working only Google Chrome but i want all browser

so please help me?

Comment: You can use this: `body { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: @Raptor wouldn't he be unable to scroll then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: @MateuszJ oops. I overlooked the question.

Comment: i try *body{overflow:hidden;}* scrollbar hide but site not scroll

Comment: See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/954/

Comment: yes its working but not working in my template Why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Firefox, Chrome, and Opera using CSS only. All work fine with it.

```
* {

    /* hide scrollbar for firefox */
    scrollbar-width: none;
}

/* hide scroll bar for chrome and opera */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    width: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

`*::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px; }`