# Materialize tab indicator always overflows

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using the tab element of the Materializecss framework and I'm trying to make a simple 3 tab slider.

For some reason, whenever I add a third tab, the bottom tab indicator always overflows to the right making a scroll bar appear:

[image]

My code is simple:

```
<div class="col s12" id="charging_history_tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s4">
            <a href="#charging_history_chart_tab">Line Chart</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab col s4">
            <a href="#charging_history_sankey_tab">Sankey Diagram</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab col s4">
            <a href="#download_tab">Download Session Data</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row" id="charging_history_chart_tab">
    <div class="col s12">
        <canvas id="charging_history_chart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="charging_history_sankey_tab">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div id="sankey_basic" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="download_tab">
    <h1> hello there!</h1>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page, maybe. maybe not

Comment: i can help you if u can show some working snippet

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enclose your tab code into a div with `class="row"` so `col` isn't rendered correctly...

Try like this:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12" id="charging_history_tabs">
          <ul class="tabs">
              <li class="tab col s4">
                  <a href="#charging_history_chart_tab">Line Chart</a>
              </li>
              <li class="tab col s4">
                  <a href="#charging_history_sankey_tab">Sankey Diagram</a>
              </li>
              <li class="tab col s4">
                  <a href="#download_tab">Download Session Data</a>
              </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A scrollbar appears because there is not enough space. If you alter the width of the container, or the elements within the container, it should work out.