# Vertical Scrollbar - Remove when not necessary

Tags: css

When creating a brand new Asp.Net MVC application with bootstrap 4.3.1 the default landing page contains a vertical scrollbar - which is silly, since the content nicely wraps and the footer is always visible?

[image]

Comment: I think I have found a solution, tweaking the default site.css as follow: html {
  position: relative;
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
  min-height: calc(100% - 1px);
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the scroll bar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scroll-bar-on-an-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a css issue?

What have you tried, you should try and show things you've tried so we are not repeating this.

Have you tried setting overflow:hidden

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, do you think my tweak in site.css to set the min-height to calc(100%-1px) is not a good option?

Comment: If it works, and renders on all browsers then its a good option.

Comment: overflow: hidden does not work - since it completely removes the scrollbar - even when there are more content that needs to be scrolled to..

Comment: overflow: auto ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using your advice to enhance the bpdy {} tag - to include overflow: hidden; however this removed the scrollbar always - even when it needs to be show.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a solution (it took care of my unnecessary vertical scrollbar ...)

Tweaking the site.css file 
1. changed the min-height: 100% to instead do a calc(100% - 1px)...

```
html {
  position: relative;
  /*min-height: 100%;*/
  min-height: calc(100% - 1px);
}
```