# How can I hide the vertical scrollbar, while still showing my horizontal, and keep scroll functionality on both?

Tags: css, angular

I want to hide my vertical scrollbar, but still be able to scroll both vertically and horizontally.

I have tried using

```
overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll;
```

But it removes the ability to scroll vertically.

I have tried styling the scrollbar with

```
html .example-container {
 scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
 -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE 10+ */
}
```

and

```
html .example-container::-webkit-scrollbar { /* WebKit */
  width: 4;
  height: 0;
}
```

It makes both scrollbars hidden, and it is important for the horizontal scrollbar to be visible.

Example of all three methods tried:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyq9ub

Answer (score 0):

Create a **wrapper div** for your **inner div** and then set inner div *overflow = auto*. And the outer div *overflow to hidden*.

For example;

```
<div class="wrapper-div">
   <div class="example-container">
      <p class="content">
        Start editing to see some magic happen :)
      </p>
      ---
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example-container {
     height: 100px;
     overflow: auto;
     max-height: 100%;
     margin-right: -100px;
     padding-right: 100px;
   }
.wrapper-div {
       overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Thats it! Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23771140/2376652) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you stylize your horizontal scrollbar then your vertical scrollbar somehow disappears and you are still able to scroll vertically as you asked. But it's unclear to me why it works

```
.example-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.example-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background: #a1a1a1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

/* Track */
.example-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```