# How to remove scroll bar after making the website responsive?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

After I made responsive using vanilla CSS, I am getting scroll bar in the bottom, how to get rid of this? Does Tailwind CSS provides a better solution to it?

Comment: If you have a scrollbar, then you either explicitly coded it in or you having an overflow issue. To hide a scrollbar but not disabeling the scrolling feature you should give the scrollbar a `width/height` of `0/none`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding the scroll bar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scroll-bar-on-an-html-page)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can hide scrollbars on HTML elements using css rule `overflow: hidden`. Browsers show a scrollbar by default if the contents of an element overflow the parent element's size. The equivalent Tailwind class is `overflow-hidden`

Comment: it does not just hide the scrollbar but disable the entire scrolling feature.

Comment: You will not able to see the entire page in `x & y direction` with the class mentioned in the answer.