# Why is my carousel making page extra wide?

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I am creating my portfolio website and i just implemented this carousel. All seems to work nice but when it gets scrolled to right it makes my page wide and adds a scrollbar at the bottom.

I would like the slides to just hide after screen edge on both sides.

Extra request: im also trying to figure out how to make it loop the images so they wont stop at the ends, so if you have any suggestions about that please let me know.

preview: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DBvagabond/dbogdanski/main/work.html
(js not working on my github but works locally, dont know why yet)

```js
const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

const handleOnDown = e => track.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientX;

const handleOnUp = () => {
  track.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";
  track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage;
}

const handleOnMove = e => {
  if (track.dataset.mouseDownAt === "0") return;

  const mouseDelta = parseFloat(track.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientX,
    maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;

  const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,
    nextPercentageUnconstrained = parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage) + percentage,
    nextPercentage = Math.max(Math.min(nextPercentageUnconstrained, 0), -100);

  track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;

  track.animate({
    transform: `translate(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`
  }, {
    duration: 1200,
    fill: "forwards"
  });

  for (const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
    image.animate({
      objectPosition: `${100 + nextPercentage}% center`
    }, {
      duration: 1200,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  }
}


window.onmousedown = e => handleOnDown(e);

window.ontouchstart = e => handleOnDown(e.touches[0]);

window.onmouseup = e => handleOnUp(e);

window.ontouchend = e => handleOnUp(e.touches[0]);

window.onmousemove = e => handleOnMove(e);

window.ontouchmove = e => handleOnMove(e.touches[0]);
```

```css
#image-track {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4vmin;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
}

#image-track .image {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 56vmin;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% center;
}
```

```html
<section class="wallpapers">
  <div id="image-track" data-mouse-down-at="0" data-prev-percentage="0">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524781289445-ddf8f5695861?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610194352361-4c81a6a8967e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1674&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618202133208-2907bebba9e1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495805442109-bf1cf975750b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548021682-1720ed403a5b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496753480864-3e588e0269b3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2134&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613346945084-35cccc812dd5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1759&q=80" draggable="false" />
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516681100942-77d8e7f9dd97?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: For the first part of the question you are probably looking for `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: That did the trick. I pressume it just hides the scrollbar and when scrolled to the right the page still remains wide?

Comment: It doesn't hide the scrollbar, it hides the part of elements overflowing (so there is no scrollbar). To hide a scrollbar you can check [Hiding the scroll bar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scroll-bar-on-an-html-page) but that means you still can navigate with `←` and `→` keys for example