# How to remove scrollbar in angular, css, js or html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I am new in frontend, I have searched this issue and didn't find answer. Is there any way to remove scrollbar from this page in img? Or some ways to make page height stable?

my html page

[image: 1]

I need to make this page unscrollable

Comment: It would be great to see some html+ccs of yours.
One of the solutions is:
body {
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding the scroll bar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scroll-bar-on-an-html-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the scrollbar in an Angular app, you can apply CSS to the body element to set the overflow property to hidden.
In your Angular component's CSS file, add

```
body {overflow: hidden;}
```