# disable scroll bar in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable browsers vertical and horizontal scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars)

Can I disable vertical scroll bar in IE.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars

Comment: Yes you can.  Would a user like you to?  Probably not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to disable the scroll bar for a form element, you can use the following code:

```
style="overflow-y:hidden"
```

If you want the actual browser to not have a scroll bar, you can apply the same style to the html element.

```
html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

If you want to disable both scroll bars:

```
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 3):

And in case you want to use just html attributes:

```
<body scroll="no">
```

to disable scroll in IE completely

Let the down voting begin ;)

Comment: It really does deserve a down vote, why would you suggest a non-standard html attribute when people have mentioned perfectly good solutions?

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you can do:

```
html, body {
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling scroll bars with css

```
overflow-x:hidden
overflow-y:hidden
```