# Kill vertical scrolling when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup

I have a js popup. It pops up when a link is clicked. I want to disable (vertical) scrolling on the page when that link is clicked, and then reactivate scrolling when the popup is closed. Is there any way to do this? jQuery, Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars - using this disabled scrolling in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set `overflow hidden` to disable the scrolling.

```
$('#yourDiv').css('overflow','hidden');
```

and to set scrol

```
 $('#yourDiv').css('overflow','scroll')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the vertical scrolling by keeping the popup `position : fixed` in css. 
Or you can do is keep `overflow : hidden` for `body` 
If you want this to be done from JavaScript then jQuery has the solution to change the css from `.css()` :)

Comment: I think the OP wants to achieve fixing the popup position in the viewport. IIRC, position:fixed fixes an element's position relative to its containing element, not the browser viewport.