# Possible to disable scrollbar instead of hiding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to disable a scrollbar instead of hiding it on a page? I want it to stay on the page when I open a modal dialog, I just don't want the users to be able to scroll the main page. So the perfect functionality would be:

short page - no scrollbar at all;

long page - scrollbar appears;

long page modal dialog open - scrollbar still there, but cannot be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable browsers vertical and horizontal scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars)

Comment: I don't want to hide the scrollbar because it creates a page shift by the scrollbar width. If possible, I'd like to disable it, grey out or whatever is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it

Answer (score 3):

Well when you have a modal you can just play around with the `onscroll` of `window`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DmmEv/

Code:

```
var scrollX = window.scrollX, scrollY = window.scrollY;
window.onscroll = function(e){
    scroll(scrollX,scrollY)
}
```

---

**Real Example**:
Scrollbars will stay in place after clicking on `Click Me`
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DmmEv/6/

Comment: This comment should get the vote! Works like a charm.

Comment: This is **not** a comment. This is an **answer**.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
<body style="overflow: scroll;">
Hello
<body>
```

Comment: Woudln't it make the scrollbar appear at all times? I don't really want it to be there where the page is short. or would it be still possible for the users to use it when a modal dialog appears?

Comment: Oh I thought that's what you wanted.  Okay so change `scroll` to `auto`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it works in FF, but users are still able to use scrollbar in older IE.

Comment: I guess I'm not following what you want.  Do you want to show the scrollbars or not?

Comment: like I mentioned in the question. I don't want the scrollbar to show when the page is short, and I want it to show when it's long, but I want the scrollbar to be disabled when a modal dialog opens up on a long page with a scrollbar. hope that's clear :)