# How to disable scroll without hiding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to disable the html/body scrollbar of the parent while I'm using a lightbox. The main word here is *disable*. I do *not* want to hide it with `overflow: hidden;`.

The reason for this is that `overflow: hidden` makes the site jump and take up the area where the scroll was.

I want to know if its possible to disable a scrollbar while still showing it.

Comment: Should any scrolling be possible? (Does the lightbox have any scrollbars?)

Comment: the site got scrolling but i just want to disable it while the lightbox is open. i just want to know if its possible to disable a scrollbar while showing it. nothing else is needed like how to do it in a lightbox or anything else.

Comment: what is the problem using lightbox with scrollbar?

Comment: @Dejan OK, but does the lightbox itself contain any scrollbars?

Comment: yes, but why is that important?

Comment: @Dejan Because I know how to disable *all* scrolling - that would disable the main scrollbar, but also the one in the lightbox...

Comment: @manny when i scroll the lightbox and it ends it starts to scroll the background, and even if the lightbox dont got scrolls i dont want the user to be able to scroll the background from the lightbox.

Comment: @Sime Vidas.. but does it disable and still show it? let me know how to

Comment: @Dejan.S See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/425275 It explains how to disable mouse scrolling altogether.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas that works when scrolling outside the lightbox but when scrolling inside it still scrolls the background. but it can work with some modifications.

Comment: With this solution; page is scrolling to top of the page when disabled body.

Comment: Please do not edit the answer back into this post.  The answer section below is for answers.  If you have an answer to your question that is _different_ from an answer below, you may add your own solution in the answer selection.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

If the page under the overlayer can be "fixed" at the top, when you open the overlay you can set

```
body { 
  position: fixed; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

you should still see the right scrollbar but the content is not scrollable. When you close the overlay just revert these properties with

```
body { 
  position: static;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

I just proposed this way only because you wouldn't need to change any scroll event

**What if I already scrolled the page?**

if you get the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` property via javascript just before the layer opening, you could dynamically assign that value as `top` property of the `body` element: with this approach the page will keep its current scroll position, no matter if you're on top or if you have already scrolled.

**Css**

```
.noscroll {
  position: fixed; 
  top: var(--st, 0);
  inline-size: 100%;
  overflow-y:scroll; 
}
```

**JS**

```
const b = document.body;
b.style.setProperty('--st', -(document.documentElement.scrollTop) + "px");
b.classList.add('noscroll');
```

Comment: it messes with my layout but with some modifications it just might work. i like this i will try it out more

Comment: with a little modification this is works. i added a width: 100%; im gone update my question with the solution but you can modify your with with the width: 100%;? thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It adds/appends a new scroll (vertical) in my application :(
Yet i want my default browser scroll(y) to be disabled for a moment of time.

Comment: I don’t know why, but this works better for me:

`$('body').css('top', -($('body').scrollTop()) + 'px').addClass('noscroll');`

Comment: Working fine with FF and Chrome. But this is not working with IE. Do I need to write IE specific additional styles for this to work in IE ?

Comment: Maybe its other code I have on my site that interferes but on Chrome 43 this is not working . It jumps to the top anyway even with your JS hack.

Comment: @whitesiroi, you are right. I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evpozdniakov/2m8km9wg/ Thank  you!

Comment: For those reading the comments for a solution, the last fiddle provides a solution for disabling and re-enabling the scrollbar whilst retaining the scrollbar position in both cases.  Thanks!

Comment: It hides the background scroller. I want that background scroller doesn't hide and a user can manually scrolls the body.

Comment: @legend add "overflow-y:scroll" to the body.scrolDisabled CSS in the last fiddle and it should work

Comment: This answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447487/html-page-scrolls-on-keydown

Comment: Save `scrollTop` as a variable, then on scroll enabling run `document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, scrollTop)`

Comment: And set `top: 0` for every `position: fixed` element, otherwise you going to get a bug

Comment: yeah, there is an issue with `fixed` elements. To solve this I've added `id="main-scrollable-content"` to the div which holds page content except fixed elements and applied `scrollableEl.style.transform = "translateY(-${this.scrollTop}px)"` instead of `top` or negative margin

Answer (score 106):

Four little additions to the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8701977/1264804):

1. Apply 'noscroll' to **html instead of to body** to prevent double scroll bars in IE
2. To **check if there's actually a scroll bar** before adding the 'noscroll' class. Otherwise, the site will also jump pushed by the new non-scrolling scroll bar.
3. To keep any possible **scrollTop** so the entire page doesn't go back to the top (like Fabrizio's update, but you need to grab the value before adding the 'noscroll' class)
4. Not all browsers handle scrollTop the same way as documented at http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php

Complete solution that seems to work for most browsers:

**CSS**

```
html.noscroll {
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Disable scroll**

```
if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
     var scrollTop = ($('html').scrollTop()) ? $('html').scrollTop() : $('body').scrollTop(); // Works for Chrome, Firefox, IE...
     $('html').addClass('noscroll').css('top',-scrollTop);         
}
```

**Enable scroll**

```
var scrollTop = parseInt($('html').css('top'));
$('html').removeClass('noscroll');
$('html,body').scrollTop(-scrollTop);
```

Thanks to Fabrizio and Dejan for putting me on the right track and to Brodingo for [the solution to the double scroll bar](https://twitter.com/Brodingo/status/29599155414)

Comment: This tested well on desktop but on the iPhone it created a blank white screen until the reader attempted to scroll the page. Once the reader tried to interact with the page, the intended screen became visible with the scroll locked.

Comment: This worked perfectly with Fancybox on iPad to disable scrolling of lightbox image with `afterLoad()` and `afterClose` callbacks. Could be useful for others searching this question.

Comment: In the "enable scroll" part, you might want to remove the style attribute that is placed on the html element after a call to "disable scroll"; don't you ?

Comment: jQuery standardises native DOM's `scrollTop` such that line 2 of the 'Disable scroll' code can be expressed as `$( window ).scrollTop()`.

Comment: I think one other thing needs to be added to this.  On Chrome in OSX, it's possible for the browser to "over-scroll", giving scrolling an elastic feel.  With this code if you are in the grey area above or below the page and you hover over a spot where you disable scrolling.  It will stick to a spot above/below the browser window.  For this reason you need to add a check for a negative scroll value: `if (scrollTop < 0) { scrollTop = 0; }`.  Here is the full code for disable https://gist.github.com/jayd3e/2eefbbc571cd1668544b.

Comment: The position fixed hack (suggested in most answers here) produces terrible UX. Body be jumpin' all over the place. This is by far the best solution.

Comment: The "Enable scroll" part is jumping slightly up and down when having a scrollTop > 0. This happens on Chrome, while Firefox handles it smoothly (both on Mac OS).

Comment: This is best solution i ever find. I tried a lot of techniques but nothing work. This is the working best...

Comment: Second line of "Enable scroll" should be $('html').removeClass('noscroll').css('top',''); For me this solved a lot of problems with a responsive menu

Comment: @PatrickRudolph I think this happens because of the vertical scrollbar, which dissapears on Chrome. The wider layout then has different line-breaks which is the reason for the jump. Forcing scrollbars with `overflow-y: scroll;` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 40):

## With jQuery inluded:

---

#### disable

```
$.fn.disableScroll = function() {
    window.oldScrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).on('scroll.scrolldisabler',function ( event ) {
       $(window).scrollTop( window.oldScrollPos );
       event.preventDefault();
    });
};
```

#### enable

```
$.fn.enableScroll = function() {
    $(window).off('scroll.scrolldisabler');
};
```

#### usage

```
//disable
$("#selector").disableScroll();
//enable
$("#selector").enableScroll();
```

Comment: this was perfect for me, the previous answer made my page bounce, this one doesn't

Comment: glad i could help, you might need to check for "touchmove" too, for mobile devices, cheers

Comment: Well, this *almost* worked for me. It worked wonders on Windows (Firefox, Chrome) and MacOS in Firefox... but then I went to Windows IE and Edge, along with MacOS in Chrome and Safari. The problem was no longer about the page jumping from side-to-side, but the scrollbar was jumping from top to current position or the page was flickering up top. Man, this was *so*, *so* close. Maybe we can still make it work.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you ! Ideal tu use on a website where the overlay menu is also at the bottom of the page !

Answer (score 22):

I'm the OP

With the help of answer from fcalderan I was able to form a solution. I leave my solution here as it brings clarity to how to use it, and adds a very crucial detail, `width: 100%;`

I add this class

```
body.noscroll
{
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this worked for me and I was using Fancyapp.

Comment: It works for me,

Your solution seems the cleanest in here,

Comment: it jumps to the top of the page

Answer (score 12):

This worked really well for me....

```
// disable scrolling
$('body').bind('mousewheel touchmove', lockScroll);

// enable scrolling
$('body').unbind('mousewheel touchmove', lockScroll);


// lock window scrolling
function lockScroll(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

just wrap those two lines of code with whatever decides when you are going to lock scrolling.

e.g.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
     $('body').bind('mousewheel touchmove', lockScroll);
});
```

Comment: This results in an error in Chrome 87:  `[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312` ([ref](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312))

Comment: You can also scroll with the arrow keys, page up/down etc. You could disable all use of arrow keys, but that creates other problems for my use case.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot disable the scroll event, but you can disable the related actions that lead to a scroll, like mousewheel and touchmove:

```
$('body').on('mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can be done with pure javascript?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can hide the body's scrollbar with `overflow: hidden` and set a margin at the same time so that the content doesn't jump:

```
let marginRightPx = 0;
if(window.getComputedStyle) {
    let bodyStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
    if(bodyStyle) {
        marginRightPx = parseInt(bodyStyle.marginRight, 10);
    }
}

let scrollbarWidthPx = window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
Object.assign(document.body.style, {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginRight: `${marginRightPx + scrollbarWidthPx}px`
});
```

And then you can add a disabled scrollbar to the page to fill in the gap:

```css
textarea {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 11px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

I did exactly this for my own lightbox implementation. Seems to be working well so far.

Comment: I actually like this method the best. Very simple and works great. Thanks!

Comment: Very simple but it comes with one caveat. This won't work when the browser renders the scrollbar on the left (RTL). 
Unfortunately, there is no simple way to detect where the browser puts the scrollbar. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52404285/2370007

Comment: Probably a marginal issue, but if the dev tools are open on the side it will count the width of the dev tools as part of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v1gke7po/). This is how you can do this with pure JavaScript:

```
const { body, documentElement } = document;
let { scrollTop } = document.documentElement;

function disableScroll() {
  scrollTop = documentElement.scrollTop;
  body.style.top = `-${scrollTop}px`;
  body.classList.add("scroll-disabled");
}

function enableScroll() {
  body.classList.remove("scroll-disabled");
  documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  body.style.removeProperty("top");
}
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.scroll-disabled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

We use `position: fixed` on `body` to prevent it from being scrollable and we use `overflow-y` to show the scrollbar. We also need to set `width` because of how `position: fixed` works.

We keep track of the scroll position and update it when disabling scroll so that we can position `body` appropriately using `top` when scroll is disabled and restore the scroll position when it is enabled. Otherwise `body` will keep jumping to the top when disabling or enabling scroll.

When enabling scroll we remove the `top` style from `body`. This prevents it from breaking your layout if you have a different `position` than `static` on `body`.

If you are using `scroll-behavior: smooth` on `html`, you also need to modify the `enableScroll` function like this:

```
function enableScroll() {
  body.classList.remove("scroll-disabled");
  // Set "scroll-behavior" to "auto"
  documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = "auto";
  documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  // Remove "scroll-behavior: auto" after restoring scroll position
  documentElement.style.removeProperty("scroll-behavior");
  body.style.removeProperty("top");
}
```

We need to temporarily set `scroll-behavior` to `auto` so that there are no jumps.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution we went with. Simply save the scroll position when the overlay is opened, scroll back to the saved position any time the user attempted to scroll the page, and turn the listener off when the overlay is closed.

It's a bit jumpy on IE, but works like a charm on Firefox/Chrome.

```js
var body = $("body"),
  overlay = $("#overlay"),
  overlayShown = false,
  overlayScrollListener = null,
  overlaySavedScrollTop = 0,
  overlaySavedScrollLeft = 0;

function showOverlay() {
  overlayShown = true;

  // Show overlay
  overlay.addClass("overlay-shown");

  // Save scroll position
  overlaySavedScrollTop = body.scrollTop();
  overlaySavedScrollLeft = body.scrollLeft();

  // Listen for scroll event
  overlayScrollListener = body.scroll(function() {
    // Scroll back to saved position
    body.scrollTop(overlaySavedScrollTop);
    body.scrollLeft(overlaySavedScrollLeft);
  });
}

function hideOverlay() {
  overlayShown = false;

  // Hide overlay
  overlay.removeClass("overlay-shown");

  // Turn scroll listener off
  if (overlayScrollListener) {
    overlayScrollListener.off();
    overlayScrollListener = null;
  }
}

// Click toggles overlay
$(window).click(function() {
  if (!overlayShown) {
    showOverlay();
  } else {
    hideOverlay();
  }
});
```

```css
/* Required */
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; background: #fff; }
html { overflow: hidden; }
body { overflow-y: scroll; }

/* Just for looks */
.spacer { height: 300%; background: orange; background: linear-gradient(#ff0, #f0f); }
.overlay { position: fixed; top: 20px; bottom: 20px; left: 20px; right: 20px; z-index: -1; background: #fff; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); overflow: auto; }
.overlay .spacer { background: linear-gradient(#88f, #0ff); }
.overlay-shown { z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Top of page</h1>
<p>Click to toggle overlay. (This is only scrollable when overlay is <em>not</em> open.)</p>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<h1>Bottom of page</h1>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
  <h1>Top of overlay</h1>
  <p>Click to toggle overlay. (Containing page is no longer scrollable, but this is.)</p>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <h1>Bottom of overlay</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Works indeed, but taints the design in case of a fixed header, as the scrollbar dives under it.

Comment: @LeonWillens I'm not sure what you mean. If you're concerned about the overlay appearing under a fixed header, you'll need to adjust the `z-index` of `.overlay-shown` to be greater than the fixed header. (I have this code running in production on a site with a fixed header and it works fine.)

Comment: No, I was talking about the scrollbar of the `body` tag. I experimented with your code yesterday and I have a fixed header at the top of my page. If I handle scrolling via the `body` tag, the scrollbar will be under the fixed header.

Comment: @LeonWillens Oops, looks like I fixed this in production at some point and forgot to update this. It looks like instead of `$("body")`, we're using `$(window)`. And instead of `z-index: -1` on the overlay to hide it, you can use `visibility: hidden` or similar. See https://jsfiddle.net/8p2gfeha/ for a quick test to see if it works. Fixed header no longer appears on top of the scrollbar. I'll eventually try to incorporate these changes into the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to get rid of content jump on fixed modal, when removing body scroll is to normalize page width:

```
body {width: 100vw; overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Then you can play with fixed position or overflow:hidden for body when the modal is open. But it will hide horizontal scrollbars - usually they're not needed on responsive website.

Answer (score 2):

I like to stick to the "overflow: hidden" method and just add padding-right that's equal to the scrollbar width.

Get scrollbar width function, by [lostsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript).

```
function getScrollbarWidth() {
    var outer = document.createElement("div");
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "100px";
    outer.style.msOverflowStyle = "scrollbar"; // needed for WinJS apps

    document.body.appendChild(outer);

    var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
    // force scrollbars
    outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

    // add innerdiv
    var inner = document.createElement("div");
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    outer.appendChild(inner);        

    var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;

    // remove divs
    outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

    return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
}
```

When showing the overlay, add "noscroll" class to html and add padding-right to body:

```
$(html).addClass("noscroll");
$(body).css("paddingRight", getScrollbarWidth() + "px");
```

When hiding, remove the class and padding:

```
$(html).removeClass("noscroll");
$(body).css("paddingRight", 0);
```

The noscroll style is just this:

```
.noscroll { overflow: hidden; }
```

Note that if you have any elements with position:fixed you need to add the padding to those elements too.

Comment: I used this solution. It helped me to avoid double scrollbars (one 'blank' for the body and a second one for the content of the overlay). It also works very well on OSX which might or might not show scrollbars at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can keep overflow:hidden but manage scroll position manually:

before showing keep trace of actual scroll position:

```
var scroll = [$(document).scrollTop(),$(document).scrollLeft()];
//show your lightbox and then reapply scroll position
$(document).scrollTop(scroll[0]).scrollLeft(scroll[1]);
```

it should work

Answer (score 1):

`<div id="lightbox">` is inside the `<body>` element, thus when you scroll the lightbox you also scroll the body. The solution is to not extend the `<body>` element over 100%, to place the long content inside another `div` element and to add a scrollbar if needed to this `div` element with `overflow: auto`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">much content</div>
    <div id="lightbox">lightbox<div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, scrolling over the lightbox (and the `body` as well) has no effect, because the body is no longer than 100% of the screen height.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: a left-hand menu that, when it appears, prevents scrolling. As soon as height was set to 100vh, the scrollbar disappeared and the content jerked to the right.

So if you don't mind keeping the scrollbar enabled (but setting the window to full height so it won't actually scroll anywhere) then another possibility is setting a tiny bottom margin, which will keep the scroll bars showing:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `overflow:hidden` prevent the margin from having any effect?

Answer (score 1):

All modal/lightbox javascript-based systems use an overflow when displaying the modal/lightbox, on html tag or body tag.

When lightbox is show, the js push a overflow hidden on html or body tag.
When lightbox is hidden, some remove the hidden other push a overflow auto on html or body tag.

Developers who work on Mac, do not see the problem of the scrollbar.

Just replace the hidden by an unset not to see the content slipping under the modal of the removal of the scrollbar.

**Lightbox open/show:**

```
<html style="overflow: unset;"></html>
```

**Lightbox close/hide:**

```
<html style="overflow: auto;"></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the page under the overlayer can be "fixed" at the top, when you open the overlay you can set

```
.disableScroll { position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll }
```

provide this class to the scrollable body, you should still see the right scrollbar but the content is not scrollable.

To maintain the position of the page do this in jquery

```
$('body').css('top', - ($(window).scrollTop()) + 'px').addClass('disableScroll');
```

When you close the overlay just revert these properties with

```
var top = $('body').position().top;
$('body').removeClass('disableScroll').css('top', 0).scrollTop(Math.abs(top));
```

I just proposed this way only because you wouldn't need to change any scroll event

Answer (score 1):

> This will stop the viewport jumping to the top by saving the scroll position and restoring it on enabling scrolling.

CSS

```
.no-scroll{
  position: fixed; 
  width:100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow-y:scroll!important;
}
```

JS

```
var scrollTopPostion = 0;

function scroll_pause(){
  scrollTopPostion = $(window).scrollTop();
  $("body").addClass("no-scroll").css({"top":-1*scrollTopPostion+"px"});
}

function scroll_resume(){
  $("body").removeClass("no-scroll").removeAttr("style");
  $(window).scrollTop(scrollTopPostion);
}
```

Now all you need to do is to call the functions

```
$(document).on("click","#DISABLEelementID",function(){
   scroll_pause();
});

$(document).on("click","#ENABLEelementID",function(){
   scroll_resume();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `position: fixed;` solution has a drawback - the page jumps to the top when this style is applied. Angular's Material Dialog has a nice solution, where they fake the scroll position by applying positioning to the `html` element.

Below is my revised algorithm for vertical scrolling only. Left scroll blocking is done in the exact same manner.

```
// This class applies the following styles:
// position: fixed;
// overflow-y: scroll;
// width: 100%;
const NO_SCROLL_CLASS = "bp-no-scroll";

const coerceCssPixelValue = value => {
  if (value == null) {
    return "";
  }

  return typeof value === "string" ? value : `${value}px`;
};

export const blockScroll = () => {
  const html = document.documentElement;
  const documentRect = html.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { body } = document;

  // Cache the current scroll position to be restored later.
  const cachedScrollPosition =
    -documentRect.top || body.scrollTop || window.scrollY || document.scrollTop || 0;

  // Cache the current inline `top` value in case the user has set it.
  const cachedHTMLTop = html.style.top || "";

  // Using `html` instead of `body`, because `body` may have a user agent margin,
  // whereas `html` is guaranteed not to have one.
  html.style.top = coerceCssPixelValue(-cachedScrollPosition);

  // Set the magic class.
  html.classList.add(NO_SCROLL_CLASS);

  // Return a function to remove the scroll block.
  return () => {
    const htmlStyle = html.style;
    const bodyStyle = body.style;

    // We will need to seamlessly restore the original scroll position using
    // `window.scroll`. To do that we will change the scroll behavior to `auto`.
    // Here we cache the current scroll behavior to restore it later.
    const previousHtmlScrollBehavior = htmlStyle.scrollBehavior || "";
    const previousBodyScrollBehavior = bodyStyle.scrollBehavior || "";

    // Restore the original inline `top` value.
    htmlStyle.top = cachedHTMLTop;

    // Remove the magic class.
    html.classList.remove(NO_SCROLL_CLASS);

    // Disable user-defined smooth scrolling temporarily while we restore the scroll position.
    htmlStyle.scrollBehavior = bodyStyle.scrollBehavior = "auto";

    // Restore the original scroll position.
    window.scroll({
      top: cachedScrollPosition.top
    });

    // Restore the original scroll behavior.
    htmlStyle.scrollBehavior = previousHtmlScrollBehavior;
    bodyStyle.scrollBehavior = previousBodyScrollBehavior;
  };
};
```

The logic is very simple and can be simplified even more if you don't care about certain edge cases. For example, this is what I use:

```
export const blockScroll = () => {
  const html = document.documentElement;
  const documentRect = html.getBoundingClientRect();
  const { body } = document;
  const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Only do the magic if document is scrollable
  if (documentRect.height > screenHeight) {
    const cachedScrollPosition =
      -documentRect.top || body.scrollTop || window.scrollY || document.scrollTop || 0;

    html.style.top = coerceCssPixelValue(-cachedScrollPosition);

    html.classList.add(NO_SCROLL_CLASS);

    return () => {
      html.classList.remove(NO_SCROLL_CLASS);

      window.scroll({
        top: cachedScrollPosition,
        behavior: "auto"
      });
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made this one function, that solves this problem with JS.
This principle can be easily extended and customized that is a big pro for me.

Using this js DOM API function:

```
const handleWheelScroll = (element) => (event) => {
  if (!element) {
    throw Error("Element for scroll was not found");
  }
  const { deltaY } = event;
  const { clientHeight, scrollTop, scrollHeight } = element;
  if (deltaY < 0) {
    if (-deltaY > scrollTop) {
      element.scrollBy({
        top: -scrollTop,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    return;
  }

  if (deltaY > scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollTop) {
    element.scrollBy({
      top: scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollTop,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
};
```

In short, this function will stop event propagation and default behavior if the scroll would scroll something else then the given element (the one you want to scroll in).

Then you can hook and unhook this up like this:

```
const wheelEventHandler = handleWheelScroll(elementToScrollIn);

window.addEventListener("wheel", wheelEventHandler, {
    passive: false,
});

window.removeEventListener("wheel", wheelEventHandler);
```

Watch out for that it is a higher order function so you have to keep a reference to the given instance.

I hook the `addEventListener` part in mouse enter and unhook the `removeEventListener` in mouse leave events in jQuery, but you can use it as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve noticed that the YouTube website does exactly this. So by inspecting it a bit I’ve been able to determine that they’re using `@polymer/iron-overlay-behavior` and fortunately, it can be used rather unobtrusively outside of web components/Polymer:

```
import {
    pushScrollLock,
    removeScrollLock,
} from '@polymer/iron-overlay-behavior/iron-scroll-manager';

// lock scroll everywhere except scrollElement
pushScrollLock(scrollElement);

// restore scrolling
removeScrollLock(scrollElement);
```

- Allows scrolling in selected element
- Doesn't mess with styling in any way
- Is battle-tested on YouTube website

It seems like a mature solution and surely the best I was able to find. The package is a bit heavy but I guess much of it become unbundled, when importing just the `iron-scroll-manager`.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have some other fixed elements in the page and setting `body`'s `position` to `fixed` caused a bunch of other problems, so I did it in a hacky way:

```js
const scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;

// on opening modal
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
document.body.style.paddingRight = `${scrollbarWidth}px`

// on closing modal
document.body.style.overflow = "unset",
document.body.style.paddingRight = "0px"
```

The idea is to add a `padding-right` with the same width as browser's scrollbar, to mimick a fake scrollbar and prevent the content shift.

Answer (score 0):

Crude but working way will be to force the scroll back to top, thus effectively disabling scrolling:

```
var _stopScroll = false;
window.onload = function(event) {
    document.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if (_stopScroll) {
            document.body.scrollTop = "0px";
        }
    }
};
```

When you open the lightbox raise the flag and when closing it,lower the flag.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/b4XcG/).

Answer (score 0):

React version:

- keeps scroll position
- no layout reflow
- typescript

```js
import type {
  PropsWithChildren
} from "react";
import {
  useCallback,
  useState,
  useContext,
  createContext
} from "react";

type BlanketContextShape = {
  isOpen ? : boolean;
  zIndex: number;
  color: string;
  setIsOpen: (yesno ? : boolean) => void;
};

const BlanketContext = createContext<BlanketContextShape>({
  zIndex: 500,
  color: `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`,
  setIsOpen() {
    return;
  },
});


function useBlanket() {
  const context = useContext(BlanketContext);
  if (!context)
    throw new Error(
      "useBlanket can only be used within children of BlanketProvider"
    );
  return context;
}


function BlanketProvider({
  children,
  color,
  zIndex,
}: PropsWithChildren<{
  zIndex ? : number;
  color ? : string;
}>) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [top, setTop] = useState(0);

  const handleSetIsOpen = useCallback(
    (yesno?: boolean) => {
      if (typeof window === "undefined") return;

      if (yesno) {
        const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
        document.body.style.top = `-${scrollTop}px`;
        setTop(scrollTop);
      }
      
      if (window.innerHeight < document.body.scrollHeight) {
        document.body.style.overflowY = (!!yesno && "scroll") || "auto";
        document.body.style.position = (!!yesno && "fixed") || "static";
      }

      window.scrollTo({ top });
      setIsOpen(() => !!yesno);
    }, [top]
  );

  return (
    <BlanketContext.Provider
      value={{
        isOpen,
        setIsOpen: handleSetIsOpen,
        color: color || `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`,
        zIndex: zIndex || 200
      }}>
    {children}
    </BlanketContext.Provider>
  );
}


function Blanket({
  children
}: PropsWithChildren) {
  const {
    isOpen,
    setIsOpen,
    zIndex,
    color
  } = useBlanket();
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen && (
        <div
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            backgroundColor: color,
            top: 0,
            height: "100vh",
            width: "100vw",
            zIndex: zIndex,
          }}
          onClick = {() => setIsOpen(false)}
        />
      )}
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

https://gist.github.com/airtonix/c8c9af146185646e7451faa0f2ac96b7

use it like:

```
// app
<BlanketProvider color='red'>
  <YourView />
</BlanketProvider>
```

```
// YourView
...
const { isOpen, setIsOpen } = useBlanket();
return (
  <>
    <Blanket>
      {isOpen && <SomeThingWithHigherZindex />}
    </Blanket>
    <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Do A Thing</Button>
  </>
)
```

When setting `isOpen` to true, we track the current scroll  from top and store it.

We only set it on the body styles if we're opening, because what we do next will cause `window.scrollY` to be `0`.

Then we test if the document is taller than the viewport.
If it is then we set the Y overflow to `scroll` to ensure that the scrollbar doesn't vanish and that there's no layout reflow jump.

Set body to position fixed, preventing it from scrolling and ensure that the document is at the correct scrolling position in order to counteract `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript:**

```
const disableScroll = () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "instant"
  })
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", disableScroll, false)
```

**React + TS:**

```
type Props = {
  open: boolean
  onClose: () => void
  disableClickOutside?: boolean
  disabledEscKey?: boolean
  width?: string
  theme?: Theme
  size?: Size
  children?: ReactNode
}

export const Modal = ({
  open,
  children,
  width,
  theme = "light",
  onClose,
  disableClickOutside,
  disabledEscKey,
  size = "md",
}: Props) => {
  const contentRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const { scrollTop } = document.documentElement

    const disableScroll = () => {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: scrollTop,
        behavior: "instant" as ScrollBehavior,
      })
    }

    if (open) {
      contentRef?.current?.focus()
      document.addEventListener("scroll", disableScroll, false)
    } else if (!open) {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", disableScroll)
    }
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", disableScroll)
    }
  }, [open])

  const handleClickOutside = (event: React.MouseEvent<Element>) => {
    if (disableClickOutside) return
    const clickedElement = event.target as HTMLDivElement
    if (!contentRef?.current?.contains(clickedElement) && open) onClose()
  }

  const handleKeydown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => {
    if (disabledEscKey) return
    if (event.key === "Escape") onClose()
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper
      aria-label="modal-wrapper"
      isOpen={open}
      onKeyDown={(e: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => handleKeydown(e)}
      onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<Element>) => handleClickOutside(e)}
      tabIndex={-1}
    >
      <Content
        theme={theme}
        ref={contentRef}
        width={width}
        size={size}
        tabIndex={1}
      >
        {children}
      </Content>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

type StyledModalProps = {
  width?: string
  theme?: Theme
  size: Size
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: ${(props: { isOpen: boolean }) => (props.isOpen ? "flex" : "none")};
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`
const Content = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: ${({ theme }: StyledModalProps) =>
    match(theme)
      .with("dark", () => Gray90)
      .otherwise(() => White)};
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1rem
    ${({ theme }: StyledModalProps) =>
      match(theme)
        .with("dark", () => "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48)")
        .otherwise(() => "rgba(28, 28, 31, 0.12)")};
  width: ${({ width, size }: StyledModalProps) =>
    width ||
    match(size)
      .with("lg", () => "67.5rem")
      .with("md", () => "45rem")
      .with("sm", () => "28.75rem")
      .with("xs", () => "20rem")
      .exhaustive()};
`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with Javascript:

```
// Classic JS
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

// jQuery
$(window).scroll(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

And then disable it when your lightbox is closed.

But if your lightbox contains a scroll bar, you won't be able to scroll while it's open. This is because `window` contains both `body` and `#lightbox`.
So you have to use an architecture like the following one:

```
<body>
  <div id="global"></div>
  <div id="lightbox"></div>
</body>
```

And then apply the `onscroll` event only on `#global`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem with a scrollLock method that set up listeners for scroll wheel events and key down events, and a preventScroll method that handled the events. Something like this:

```
preventScroll = function (e) {
    // prevent scrollwheel events
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // prevent keydown events
    var keys = [32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40];
    if (keys.includes(e.keyCode)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return false;
}

scrollLock = function (lock) {
    if (lock) {
        document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("wheel", preventScroll);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", preventScroll);
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector("#container").removeEventListener("wheel", preventScroll);
        document.querySelector("#container").removeEventListener("keydown", preventScroll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it take in account for touch devices?

Comment: Yes in the browser mobile dev sim, and yes on my Android device - untested beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a repository to solve this exact issue. Below, I have boiled the solution down to its essentials, but the repository with horizontal scrolling support and other customization options can be found here: https://github.com/alexspirgel/no-scroll

Here is a link straight to the working demo page: http://alexanderspirgel.com/no-scroll/demo/

My solution works by comparing the difference in dimensions between an outer element with a scrollbar and its inner element. Once the scrollbar size is calculated, the scrolling element can be set to `overflow: hidden` and an offset equal to the scrollbar width can be applied to prevent content shift. Additionally, this solution places a pseudo element with a disabled scrollbar in the new space created after disabling scrolling.

First, setup the html so there is an inner element wrapped by an outer element (the outer and inner elements can be the `<html>` and `<body>` elements).

```html
<html>
    <body>
        content here...
    </body>
</html>
```

The script sets CSS variables and applies the correct HTML data attributes, but the rest is controlled by the CSS. Include this CSS so the elements have the necessary styles.

```css
[data-no-scroll-element=outer] {
  --no-scroll--y-scrollbar-width: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0; /* Padding on outer elements breaks disabled scrollbar placeholder spacing. */
  overflow: auto; /* Accounts for space of internal margins. */
}

[data-no-scroll-element=outer][data-no-scroll-y-state=no-scroll] {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

[data-no-scroll-element=outer]::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[data-no-scroll-element=outer][data-no-scroll-y-state=no-scroll]::after {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

html[data-no-scroll-element=outer]::after {
  height: 100vh; /* If the outer element is <html> the after element must be set to the viewport height to work properly. */
}

[data-no-scroll-element=inner] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: none;
  max-height: none;
  border: 0; /* Border on inner elements breaks scrollbar size calculations. */
  margin: 0; /* Margin on inner elements breaks scrollbar size calculations. */
  padding: 0; /* Padding on inner elements breaks scrollbar size calculations. */
  overflow: auto; /* Accounts for space of internal margins. */
}

[data-no-scroll-element=outer][data-no-scroll-y-state=no-scroll] > [data-no-scroll-element=inner] {
  margin-right: var(--no-scroll--y-scrollbar-width, 0px);
}
```

Include this JavaScript to handle the calculation of the scrollbar width and handle the switching between enabling and disabling scrolling.

```js
class noScroll {

    static isOuterElementDocumentElement(outerElement) {
        if (outerElement === document.documentElement) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static getElementYScrollbarWidth(outerElement, innerElement) {
        let size = 0;
        let outerSize = outerElement.offsetWidth;
        if (this.isOuterElementDocumentElement(outerElement)) {
            outerSize = window.innerWidth;
        }
        const innerSize = innerElement.offsetWidth;
        const outerElementComputedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(outerElement);
        const borderLeftWidth = parseInt(outerElementComputedStyles.borderLeftWidth);
        const borderRightWidth = parseInt(outerElementComputedStyles.borderRightWidth);
        size = (outerSize - borderLeftWidth - borderRightWidth) - innerSize;
        if (size < 0) {
            size = 0;
        }
        return size;
    }

    static setYScrollbarWidthCSSVariable(outerElement, innerElement, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            value = this.getElementYScrollbarWidth(outerElement, innerElement);
        }
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            value = value.toString() + 'px';
        }
        outerElement.style.setProperty('--no-scroll--y-scrollbar-width', value);
        if (this.isOuterElementDocumentElement(outerElement)) {
            outerElement.style.setProperty('--no-scroll--document-width-offset', value);
        }
    }

    static isScrollEnabled(outerElement) {
        if (outerElement.getAttribute('data-no-scroll-y-state') === 'no-scroll') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static disableScroll(outerElement, innerElement) {
        outerElement.setAttribute('data-no-scroll-element', 'outer');
        innerElement.setAttribute('data-no-scroll-element', 'inner');
        this.setYScrollbarWidthCSSVariable(outerElement, innerElement);
        outerElement.setAttribute('data-no-scroll-y-state', 'no-scroll');
    }

    static enableScroll(outerElement, innerElement) {
        this.setYScrollbarWidthCSSVariable(outerElement, innerElement, 0);
        outerElement.setAttribute('data-no-scroll-y-state', 'scroll');
    }

    static toggleScroll(outerElement, innerElement) {
        const isScrollEnabled = this.isScrollEnabled(outerElement);
        if (isScrollEnabled) {
            this.disableScroll(outerElement, innerElement);
        }
        else {
            this.enableScroll(outerElement, innerElement);
        }
    }

};
```

Then the scroll can be disabled/enabled as you see fit by calling the methods like this:

```js
const outerElement = document.querySelector('html');
const innerElement = document.querySelector('body');

// disable
noScroll.disableScroll(outerElement, innerElement);

// enable
noScroll.enableScroll(outerElement, innerElement);

// toggle
noScroll.toggleScroll(outerElement, innerElement);
```

If you are disabling scroll on the `<html>` element, the width of the website will change. This will cause `position: fixed` elements to have the undesirable "jump" in position. To solve this, when disabling scroll of the `<html>` element, a CSS variable called `--no-scroll--document-width-offset` is created with a value equal to the change in width. You can include this CSS variable in the position of fixed elements to prevent the "jump" like so:

```
.fixed-centered {
    position: fixed;
    left: calc((100% - var(--no-scroll--document-width-offset, 0px)) / 2);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

I hope this works for you. Again this is a boiled down version of my more complete solution located here: https://github.com/alexspirgel/no-scroll

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34675476)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani thank you for your feedback. I have taken it into account and updated my answer. As this is my first answer I appreciate your help. Let me know if this is an improvement.

Comment: This is an improvement :)