# deactivate scrolling but show scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

When ever i changed height of body and HTML to 100% scroll bar of page disappears , how do i stop that

[i'm getting two scrollbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUb9t.png) after that [trying this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336300/deactivate-bodys-scrolling-but-keep-scroll-bar)

thank you

Comment: Please add the code you have made or check how to create an example to replicate the problem. On the other hand try to add the following in body overflow: hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the `css`, which will remove the `scrollbar`, and as you said change the layout of the page, try calling a `jquery function` instead.

**JS**

```
// call your pop up and inside that function add below
$('body').on('scroll mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
});
```

> Then when you close the modal, call the same function but replace `on`
> with `off`

Comment: i hate Jquery but i can do that in vanilla js , thanks