# How to DISABLE scrollbar in webpage? (not HIDE scrollbar)

Tags: html, css

using:

```
$('body,html').css("overflow","hidden");
```

the scrollbar in the page was able to hide completely. But i want the scroll bar just to be **DISABLED** during some AJAX event. Later using:

`$('body,html').css("overflow","visible");`

I had to enable scrolling again for full page in my AJAX success.

**(Like removing scrollbox from scorllbar and disabling scrolling arrows)** yet still scrollbar appears in th window. This would prevent from change of page width in meantime.

Is there any possibilitioes to do so?
Any help is appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to be more clear in your explanation...

Comment: You can probably find the answer using this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it

Comment: There is a great answer from @Patrick DaVader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery. Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 25):

OK here is the Working Code:

```
body
{
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I used it and its the same what you want.

Comment: Are the `position` and `width` really necessary?

Comment: @gvee yes, the position keeps the body element from moving when scrolling. The width ensures the body fits the screen, but I would add height: 100% as well.

Comment: This is the technique used by Facebook to disable the scrollbar on the main page while a popup is showing by the way

Comment: This makes my React app jump to the top of the page when I activate the CSS. Anyone else? Any ideas? ChatGPT helped me get it to stop scrolling to the top of the page when the CSS is applied (aka my modal was opened), but the window still insta-scrolled to the top of the page after the CSS was unapplied (aka my modal was closed). Whatever Instagram does when a modal is opened after clicking an Instagram photo is perfect.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
         overflow:hidden;
       }
</style>
```

Comment: OP already knows this solution. This solution removes the scrollbar; OP needs it to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the scrollbar click- and drag-function you can render a hidden div in front of the scrollbar with `position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; height: 100%; width: 25px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Bg9zp/ (htm-class could be your html/body)

So it is disabled for clicks, but the scroll-functionality is'nt disabled. (you can scroll with mousewheel and with "select text by pulling mouse out of the textbox")

If you want to disable the scroll-functionality, you have to add another div that disable user input without the "disabled-opacity":

http://jsfiddle.net/dKP53/ (htm-class could be your html/body)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think there isn't a solution with CSS because it's not implemented directly.

I have found 2 solutions, but I like the second one more:

1. Set the margin by yourself with JS and not with CSS. The scrollbar has a width of 17px, so the margins you get, like in the code sample. when you don't need the scroll lock, just set `margin:auto; overflow-y:auto;` again. The disadvantage of this method is, when the user zooms in, he maybe can't see the rest of the div.

   ```
   margin-left = (bodywidth - sitewidth) / 2 - 17;
   margin-right = (bodywidth - sitewidth) / 2 + 17;
   overflow-y:hidden;
   ```
2. Lock the scrolling with JS. Take the  `window.onscroll`-event. Take the `scrollMethod2`, it's more difficult, but it's better in nearly any way. This works perfectly for me without lag (doesn't 'boomerang' you back, you really stay at the scroll position (scrollMethod) or in the scrollable part (scrollMethod2)).
   Here a sample:

   ```
   // scroll lock needed? Set it in your method
   var scrollLock = false;
   window.onresize = function() {
       if (scrollLock) {
           scrollMethod();
       }
   }

   // Set here your fix scroll position
   var fixYScrollPosition = 0;
   // this method makes that you only can scroll horizontal
   function scrollMethod(){
       // scrolls to position
       window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, fixYScrollPosition); // window.scrollX gives actual position
   }

   // when you zoom in or you have a div which is scrollable, you can watch only the height of the div
   function scrollMethod2() {
       var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
       // the actual y scroll position
       var scrollHeight = window.scrollY;
       // the height of the div under the window
       var restHeight = scrollableDivHeight - (scrollHeight + windowHeight);
       // the height of the div over the window
       var topDivHeight = scrollHeight - /* the height of the content over the div */;
       // Set the scroll position if needed
       if (restHeight <= 0) {
           // don't let the user go under the div
           window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, scrollHeight + restHeight);
       }
       else if (scrollHeight - /* the height of the content over the div */ < 0) {
           // don't let the user go over the div
           window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, scrollHeight - topDivHeight);
       }
   }
   ```

Hope everything is correct. Thank you for reading, hope this helps you or gave you an idea, how to do it :)

EDIT:
You can also hide the standard scrollbar and replace it with a custom one. [Here](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html) you can find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none; 
}
```