# HTML page scrolls on keydown

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I have a game in which the player can move using the arrow keys, I when I hit the up or down arrows the screen also moves. Is there a way to disable this?

I'm using the following:
Local HTML page, Google Chrome, Windows

(FYI - the entire page isn't displayed at one time)

Here is my code:

```
function moveCharacter()
{
    // left arrow
    if (keys[37])
    {
        move("left");
    }
    // up arrow
    if (keys[38])
    {
        move("up");
    }
    // right arrow
    if (keys[39])
    {
        move("right");
    }
    // down arrow
    if (keys[40])
    {
        move("down");
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e)
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    moveCharacter();
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e)
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is because after you observe the arrow key press, the default action continues to happen - scrolling the screen. The

```
event.preventDefault()
```

method stops the default action of an event from happening.

---

Now, you only want to prevent the default action of the arrow keys, *not* all keys, or else you will lose other key events or functions like typing in an input field, for example. The code below encapsulates this idea.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  // Only intercept the arrow keys, not all keys
  if([37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your code
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    moveCharacter();
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: thanks - I realized that you could just use e.preventDefault(); at the start and not use indexOf and the curly braces :) (see answer section in my question)

Comment: Of course. However, if there are other keys besides the arrows, or text inputs, then they will be lost. That is why there is the strict check for only arrows.