# How to restrict scrolling to the div that mouse is currently hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a div name scrollable and whenever I hover mouse over it I want scrolling limited to this div only so that after reaching top/bottom of the div, scrolling will be stuck to the div. I've used the following code:

```
<div class="scrollable" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 2px;" 
 onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden'" 
 onmouseout="document.body.style.overflow='auto'" >
   Some text<br>sometext<br>sometext 
</div>
```

Doing this gets the job done, but only problem as main scrollbar is hidden the webpage looks weird everytime I hover over '.scrollable'

Also using `window.onwheel=function(){return false;}` doesnt help as it prevents scrolling of anyelement.

Is there a way to enable scrolling only on hovered div and not on others while keeping main page scrollbar visible?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything, this behavior comes by default.

Comment: it really doesnt 
when i reach bottom or top of the div scrolling further moves the main page

Comment: Then make the scrollbar to whole page always hidden something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it

Comment: I thought about that, tried it but it doesnt look good on my website, I was wondering how facebook does it, when I open my chat box and scroll in it, scrolling works only in it, while keeping main page's scrollbar visible and unaffected even if I scroll at bottom/top in the chatbox.
That's exactly what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable scrolling without hiding the scrollbar, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it) post.

Using jQuery, this would lead to:

```
$(".scroll").hover(function() {
  var oldScrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

  $(window).on('scroll.scrolldisabler', function(event) {
    $(window).scrollTop(oldScrollPos);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}, function() {
  $(window).off('scroll.scrolldisabler');
});
```

Check [it](https://jsfiddle.net/bshjxxa6/) out.

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, hopefully can work

```
        $('body').on('mousewheel', '.someDIVClass', (e: any) => {    
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
                // You can get scroll value here to do other things
            }
            else {
                // You can get scroll value here to do  other things
            }    

            // This will prevent window to scroll
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();    
        });
```