# Vertical scrollable div inside container

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the picture, please:

[image]

I would like to get this result:

[image]

I have a .row which has many column elements that is vertically scrollable. The problem is that head element (.ion-content > .scroll-content) extends scroll bar.
How can I make scroll bar in head element was active but without scrolling? (second screen).

My code:

```css
header.nav {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
header.nav .toolbar {
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 56px;
}
.tabs {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs .tabbar {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #132843;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.tabs .tabbar a.button {
    min-height: 56px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgba(123, 122, 122, 0.7);
    padding: 0;
}
.tabs .tabpanel {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    contain: strict;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-page.ion-page {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ion-content {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #212121;
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    contain: layout size style;
}
.ion-content > .fixed-content {
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 56px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
.ion-content > .scroll-content {
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 56px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    will-change: scroll-position;
    contain: size style layout;
}
.grid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid .row .col {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.grid .row .col .scrolly {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.grid .row .col .scrolly .scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    will-change: scroll-position;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header class="nav">
    <div class="toolbar"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabbar"><a class="button"></a></div>
    <div class="tabpanel">
      <div class="gallery-page ion-page">
        <div class="ion-content">
          <div class="fixed-content"></div>
          <div class="scroll-content">
            <div class="grid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="scrolly">
                     <div class="scroll-content">
                       <p>
                       (I) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et nunc eget lorem vestibulum mollis. Sed condimentum viverra finibus. Vivamus id ex fermentum, pulvinar elit at, pretium eros. Suspendisse nec rhoncus tellus. Vivamus vitae aliquet tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis eget dolor quis diam sagittis eleifend. Quisque faucibus, quam non auctor ultricies, mauris magna mollis sapien, at hendrerit lacus leo a diam. Praesent at tellus facilisis, dignissim lectus id, fermentum tellus. Pellentesque venenatis, diam nec molestie fringilla, turpis libero gravida nisi, sit amet rutrum sem nisl in odio. Donec ac hendrerit neque. Nam dignissim ex massa, id varius purus tempus a. Nam eu sem ut quam porttitor aliquam.

Sed efficitur tincidunt egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam eleifend, leo rhoncus placerat maximus, eros ex fermentum lacus, efficitur lacinia orci neque ac purus. Integer elit nulla, ornare ut vulputate vitae, lacinia et odio. Proin vel vestibulum lorem. Integer suscipit nibh dolor, sed dictum velit malesuada nec. Nullam nec laoreet magna. Mauris tempus, mi ut placerat commodo, sem massa faucibus enim, quis varius nibh purus non nulla. Mauris in metus et nisl blandit pharetra.
                       </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="scrolly">
                     <div class="scroll-content">
                       <p>
                       (II) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et nunc eget lorem vestibulum mollis. Sed condimentum viverra finibus. Vivamus id ex fermentum, pulvinar elit at, pretium eros. Suspendisse nec rhoncus tellus. Vivamus vitae aliquet tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis eget dolor quis diam sagittis eleifend. Quisque faucibus, quam non auctor ultricies, mauris magna mollis sapien, at hendrerit lacus leo a diam. Praesent at tellus facilisis, dignissim lectus id, fermentum tellus. Pellentesque venenatis, diam nec molestie fringilla, turpis libero gravida nisi, sit amet rutrum sem nisl in odio. Donec ac hendrerit neque. Nam dignissim ex massa, id varius purus tempus a. Nam eu sem ut quam porttitor aliquam.

Sed efficitur tincidunt egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam eleifend, leo rhoncus placerat maximus, eros ex fermentum lacus, efficitur lacinia orci neque ac purus. Integer elit nulla, ornare ut vulputate vitae, lacinia et odio. Proin vel vestibulum lorem. Integer suscipit nibh dolor, sed dictum velit malesuada nec. Nullam nec laoreet magna. Mauris tempus, mi ut placerat commodo, sem massa faucibus enim, quis varius nibh purus non nulla. Mauris in metus et nisl blandit pharetra.
                       </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s4yLywqj/

Did you have similar problem and can you help me, please?

Comment: set `overflow-y: hidden` to `.ion-content > .scroll-content`. Then a fast way to let you scroll until the end of the text is to add a padding-bottom (~50px) to `.scroll-content > p`

Comment: Scroll bar in head element must be visibility, but without scrollable. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/s4yLywqj/1/  (add a margin-bottom ~120px to .scrolly .scroll-content) scroll bar in columns is good, but unfortunately head element scroll bar is scrollable.

Comment: @Piotr this might help you to resolve your problem, please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `.scrolly` class to use a calculated CSS height, you can get your desired output.

```css
header.nav {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
header.nav .toolbar {
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 56px;
}
.tabs {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs .tabbar {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #132843;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.tabs .tabbar a.button {
    min-height: 56px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgba(123, 122, 122, 0.7);
    padding: 0;
}
.tabs .tabpanel {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    contain: strict;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-page.ion-page {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ion-content {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #212121;
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    contain: layout size style;
}
.ion-content > .fixed-content {
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 56px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
.ion-content > .scroll-content {
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 56px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    will-change: scroll-position;
    contain: size style layout;
}
.grid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}
.grid .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid .row .col {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.grid .row .col .scrolly {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100vh - 122px);
}
.grid .row .col .scrolly .scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    will-change: scroll-position;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header class="nav">
    <div class="toolbar"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabbar"><a class="button"></a></div>
    <div class="tabpanel">
      <div class="gallery-page ion-page">
        <div class="ion-content">
          <div class="fixed-content"></div>
          <div class="scroll-content">
            <div class="grid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="scrolly">
                     <div class="scroll-content">
                       <p>
                       (I) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et nunc eget lorem vestibulum mollis. Sed condimentum viverra finibus. Vivamus id ex fermentum, pulvinar elit at, pretium eros. Suspendisse nec rhoncus tellus. Vivamus vitae aliquet tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis eget dolor quis diam sagittis eleifend. Quisque faucibus, quam non auctor ultricies, mauris magna mollis sapien, at hendrerit lacus leo a diam. Praesent at tellus facilisis, dignissim lectus id, fermentum tellus. Pellentesque venenatis, diam nec molestie fringilla, turpis libero gravida nisi, sit amet rutrum sem nisl in odio. Donec ac hendrerit neque. Nam dignissim ex massa, id varius purus tempus a. Nam eu sem ut quam porttitor aliquam.

Sed efficitur tincidunt egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam eleifend, leo rhoncus placerat maximus, eros ex fermentum lacus, efficitur lacinia orci neque ac purus. Integer elit nulla, ornare ut vulputate vitae, lacinia et odio. Proin vel vestibulum lorem. Integer suscipit nibh dolor, sed dictum velit malesuada nec. Nullam nec laoreet magna. Mauris tempus, mi ut placerat commodo, sem massa faucibus enim, quis varius nibh purus non nulla. Mauris in metus et nisl blandit pharetra.
                       </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="scrolly">
                     <div class="scroll-content">
                       <p>
                       (II) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et nunc eget lorem vestibulum mollis. Sed condimentum viverra finibus. Vivamus id ex fermentum, pulvinar elit at, pretium eros. Suspendisse nec rhoncus tellus. Vivamus vitae aliquet tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis eget dolor quis diam sagittis eleifend. Quisque faucibus, quam non auctor ultricies, mauris magna mollis sapien, at hendrerit lacus leo a diam. Praesent at tellus facilisis, dignissim lectus id, fermentum tellus. Pellentesque venenatis, diam nec molestie fringilla, turpis libero gravida nisi, sit amet rutrum sem nisl in odio. Donec ac hendrerit neque. Nam dignissim ex massa, id varius purus tempus a. Nam eu sem ut quam porttitor aliquam.

Sed efficitur tincidunt egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam eleifend, leo rhoncus placerat maximus, eros ex fermentum lacus, efficitur lacinia orci neque ac purus. Integer elit nulla, ornare ut vulputate vitae, lacinia et odio. Proin vel vestibulum lorem. Integer suscipit nibh dolor, sed dictum velit malesuada nec. Nullam nec laoreet magna. Mauris tempus, mi ut placerat commodo, sem massa faucibus enim, quis varius nibh purus non nulla. Mauris in metus et nisl blandit pharetra.
                       </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```