# Disable scrolling after toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I disable scrolling on a whole page when I toggle the following:

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  $('html, body').css({
   overflow: 'hidden',
   height: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input id="test" type="checkbox">
  
  <span class="menu">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </span>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Just disable scroll not hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it)

Comment: I am struggeling to implement this into my code

Comment: The code you've posted here works perfectly, you just don't see it do anything because there isn't enough content on the page for it to overflow the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate the CSS and javascript part, and use the checked value of the checkbox to enable/disable the scrolling:

```js
$("#scrolltoggle").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $("body").addClass("noscroll");
  }else{
    $("body").removeClass('noscroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.example {
  height: 400px;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class='example'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='scrolltoggle'>Disable Scrolling
  </div>
</body>
```