# Page jumps to top when fullscreen menu open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using some code to disable scrolling and also retain the scrollbar when the fullscreen menu is active, but when the menu is opened by clicking the hamburger icon, the page jumps to the top. Any idea how to stop this happening?

```
.noscroll {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

````
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function () {
      $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');
    })
    
    $(document).on('click','.btn-close-menu', function(event){
        $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');( {}, event);
    })
       
});```
````

Comment: is the .btn-open-menu an <a> tag? If yes you need to pass the event in function () and then preventDefault. If it's an <a> tag answer here and I'll post a proper answer

Comment: Yes its an <a> tag, could you post the amended code below so I can understand please?

Comment: What do you have as href attribute on the a tag? Asking to complete the answer

Comment: There is no href

```<a class="btn-open-menu" style="display: none;"> <span class="line line-1"></span> <span class="line line-2"></span> <span class="line line-3"></span> </a>```

Comment: In that case the issue is not what I though. I suspect I know what could be the real issue though so I'll post an answer nonetheless, but you should consider creating a code snipped the replicates the issue, right now we're all just speculating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like:

I am using some code to disable scrolling and also retain the scrollbar when the fullscreen menu is active, but when the menu is opened by clicking the hamburger icon, the page jumps to the top. Any idea how to stop this happening?

```
.noscroll {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.btn-open-menu').click(function () {
      let scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('html, body').addClass('noscroll');
      $('html, body').css('top', '-'+scrollPosition+'px');
      $('html, body').attr('data-scroll', scrollPosition);
    })
    
    $(document).on('click','.btn-close-menu', function(event){
        $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');( {}, event);
        $(document).scrollTop( $('html, body').attr('data-scroll') )
    })
       
});
```

This will make the body fixed, but it will set its position to the current scroll position instead of the top of the page.

EDIT:
Try saving the scrollposition to element attribute so you can access it while closing the menu and set the document scroll position accordingly

Comment: This seems to work when opening the menu, but when I close the menu it jump to the top now?

Comment: Try the example after edit, you have to somehow save the position when opening menu so you can use it when closing

Comment: still jumping to top on close

Comment: Sorry, the value has to be added inside of brackets, not with "=" sign
Also, have you checked if the attribute is being created with value?

Comment: This is working now but when closing the menu it auto scrolls from the top of the page to wherever I was on the page when I opened the menu, is there anyway to stop the scrolling so it just takes you to where you were on the page instantly?

Comment: The Scrolltop function should not be animated unless you specify it should, try looking around, if you've set some kind of animation/transition rule

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your css, I use a similar system on some of my sites and the css I use is just:

```
.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: yeh this works but it makes the page jump sideways as the scrollbar gets hidden. Using ```position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll;``` makes the scrollbar visible so that the content doesnt jump sideways, but now i have the issue with the page jumping to the top.

Comment: Have you tried the method from this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/how-to-disable-scroll-without-hiding-it