# scrollbar cutting off div background

Tags: html, css

Whenever my website is viewed with a resolution that is insufficient to display the full page, a horizontal scrollbar is added. The problem is that my 100% width div with background image does not apply this background image to the portion that extends beyond the scroll bar.

This same issue is actually appears here on Stack Overflow as well. If you shrink your window small enough that you have a horizontal scrollbar, you can see that both the header and footer  div areas do not extend the background image/color.

One way I have figured to resolve this is to set the header/footer div to fixed but then the content past the end of the div is lost :-(

Anyone have any suggestions or a workaround? ty!

Answer (score 3):

When you set an element to 100% width it will have the same width as its parent element. The body tag's width defaults to the width of the viewport. According to the standard, when an elements contents is to big to fit in it, it will overflow. This is what you're seeing.

To get around this, set the min-width on the body tag. Something like the following, obviously change the width to whatever works for you:

```
body {
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Surly if you used something along the lines of

```
body{
     background: url("yourdir/yourimage.jpg") repeat repeat;
}
```

Instead of having a background div? It'd be helpful if you also added the code for the background div

Answer (score 0):

This margin is a browser scrollbar that appears during resizing and makes viewport smaller. This can be easily fixed by adding hidden overflow to body. Check [#242684](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars#answer-242684)