# Stop page from vertically scrolling when side scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling, skrollr

on **http://2fb.me** (feel free to demo the App) I'm using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and implemented a slider based on http://jsfiddle.net/GpPHx/2/

As you can see on the [webpage](http://2fb.me), the slider scrolls left and right smoothly but it also scrolls the page vertically when it doesn't need to.

How do I stop this behavior and only let it scroll left to right with the mouse-wheel and up and down and then left to right when needed because of screen resolution?

```
 <div class="scrollcontainer" id="skrollr-body"
    data-0="left:0px;"
    data-250="left:-730px;"
    >(box divs)</div>
```

Comment: According to an almost similar post, you can use CSS: `<body style="overflow: hidden">` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars

Comment: just tested, overflow:hidden on the body breaks the slider

Comment: can I use some combination of fixed positioning?

Comment: Ok then I guess I have to ask, Do you mean to stop the page from scrolling when a User is scrolling an element on the page? Or do you mean that the page scrolls vertically when you use the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: Its an issue likely specific to the skrollr lib. I should have mentioned that in the tags. I almost had it but decided to switch to iScroll which has touch capability too. I may switch back to skrollr because so far iScroll has that same problem.

Comment: Try `overflow-y:hidden`?

Comment: went back to skrollr and still having issues :|